# How can you programmatically tell an HTML SELECT to drop down (for example, due to mouseover)?

Tags: javascript, html

How can you programmatically tell an HTML `select` to drop down (for example, due to mouseover)?

Comment: I'd recommend not screwing with the behavior of the default `<select>`, as people expect it to behave a certain way and you'll be preventing people on other platforms (like mobile) from using your site.

Comment: @BrianDonovan It's not like you can't add some handling for that.

Comment: @shasikanth: your fiddle doesn't work neither in Firefox 37 nr in Chrome

Comment: Ok, i think the fiddle worked previously. Anyways I would be deleting my comment here.

Comment: @BrianDonovan Actually, mobile is a good use case of this... programatically generating a select and then having its options automatically pop up.

Comment: We shouldn't be doing this anymore. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39635285/4015856

Comment: Well now it's 2020, but for someone who is still struggling to get this thing to work, html nativeElements have methods that can be used to do exactly these kind of things, & has a method called click() which simulates a mouse click on an element, this can be used in javascript - referenced from https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp

Comment: @Hasintha Abeykoon calling click on a <select> element does not open it in Chrome 109

Comment: Have a look at Caleb Hillary's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68036061/5263950 . Works perfectly in 2024 with several browers, even with old Interne Explorer. Preserves  CSS styles, native focusability and keyboard navigation. Does not require any CSS.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't do this with a HTML select tag, but you can do it with JavaScript *and* HTML. There are variety of existing controls that do this - for instance, the "suggest" list attached to the SO "interesting/ignored tag" entry, or Gmail's lookup for email adresses.

There are many JavaScript+HTML controls that provide this capability--look for autocomplete controls for ideas.

See this link for the Autocomplete control...http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/

Comment: this is a crying shame - mobile browsers provide an OS specific scrolling list, and I need that to pop up automatically.

Answer (score 129):

*This used to actually be possible with HTML+Javascript, despite everywhere else people say it is not, but it was deprecated later on and does not work now.*

**However, this only worked in Chrome. Read more if you're interested.**

---

According to [W3C Working Draft for HTML5, Section 3.2.5.1.7. Interactive Content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#interactive-content):

> Certain elements in HTML have an activation behavior, which means that the user can activate them. This triggers a sequence of events dependent on the activation mechanism [...] **for instance using keyboard or voice input, or through mouse clicks**.

> When the user triggers an element with a defined activation behavior in a manner other than clicking it, **the default action of the interaction event must be to run** synthetic click activation steps on the element.

`<select>` being an Interactive Content, I believed that it is possible to programatically display its `<option>`s.  After a few hours of playing around, I discovered that using `document.createEvent()` and `.dispatchEvent()` works.

That said, demo time.  [**Here is a working Fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/fz2sY/39/)

```js
// <select> element displays its options on mousedown, not click.
showDropdown = function(element) {
  var event;
  event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
  event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
  element.dispatchEvent(event);
};

// This isn't magic.
window.runThis = function() {
  var dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
  showDropdown(dropdown);
};
```

```html
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="Red">Red</option>
  <option value="Green">Green</option>
  <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
</select>
<br>
<button id="fire" type="button" onclick="runThis()">Show dropdown items</button>​
```

If anyone finds a way to do the same but not in Chrome, [please feel free to modify this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fz2sY/39/).
​

Comment: Thank you for this! I needed to emulate the ALT+DOWN ARROW behavior of IE precisely in Chrome.

Comment: I wish I could add to your bounty for this. Thank you so much.

Comment: I am saddened to report that while this method does appear to work in Android webviews (e.g. Phonegap), the same can not be said for iOS. As of 2013-07-25, tested on iOS6 and Android 4.2.2.

Comment: Good to know. Keep trying!

Comment: Not working on: `IE10`, `FF 24`. Works on: `Chrome 30`, `Safari 6.0.5`, `Opera 16`

Comment: In Chrome, I changed `var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'); event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);` to this: `var event = new MouseEvent('mousedown');` and it still worked. More succinct code and not using deprecated methods.

Comment: Works on iOS6 + 7 also

Comment: @AdamTuttle It does not work on Android 4.4.2 either

Comment: `iniMouseEvent` seems to work, but why does `$(select).trigger('mousedown')` doesn't work ?

Comment: @Hernant_Negi initMouseEvent() is Deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/initMouseEvent

Comment: @XavierHo Fiddle not working in chrome version 53+. We can't perform default action for on un-trusted events. Will add an answer providing details.

Comment: It is now deprecated on [Chrome 53+](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5718803933560832)

Comment: As others have said, doesn't work on newer browsers.

Comment: Does not work in: Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: You should update your answer as this does not work in newer version of browsers.

Comment: Seems like it has been deprecated. Anyone knows an alternative solution?

Comment: Wish I didn't waste 15 minutes trying to get it work before reading a little further to know it's deprecated

Comment: Not working in Brave Version 1.47 based on Chromium: 109.0, not working in Firefox 115.7.0esr, and could not be tested with Internet Explorer 11. Look at Caleb Hillary's answer for a way more compatible solution, which is however currently not working with Chrome on smartphones: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68036061/5263950

Answer (score 51):

Xavier Ho's answer is covering how to solve the issue in most browsers currently out there. But, **it's good practice 'not to dispatch/modify' events by JavaScript anymore**. (Like, `mousedown` in this case)

From version 53+, Google Chrome **will not perform default action for un-trusted events**. Such as events created or modified by script, or dispatched via `dispatchEvent` method. This change is for aligning with Firefox and IE which I think already not performing the action.

For testing purposes, [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fz2sY/39/) provided Xavier's answer won't work in chrome 53+. (I don't test it FF and IE).

Links for reference:

https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5718803933560832
https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6461137440735232

And initMouseEvent is also [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/initMouseEvent)

Comment: Can it be done using MouseEvents? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent

Comment: I don't think so. did you try anything?

Answer (score 46):

I have this same problem and the easier way I found to solve this was with HTML and CSS.

First, make you `<select>` transparent (`opacity: 0;`). Then, place your button over the `<select>`. The click over the button will be caught by the `<select>` component.

```css
select{
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
select:hover~button {
  background: orange;
}
 div * {
 width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select>
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option>option 2</option>
    <option>option 3</option>
  </select>
  <button>click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Been a long time since I've seen this approach, and is the reference I was hoping to find. Better with extra CSS to match hidden select's size to trigger (button, img, div, etc)... 1) Ensures clickable region fills trigger 2) Menu opens directly below trigger. Note: Might also need to add a z-index to ensure the clickable region is the top-most element in some layouts.

Comment: however, if the user scrolls down the page, then the button moves accordingly but the select keeps at the same position; not really as expected. any solution for this?

Comment: Perfect solution. But better maybe wrap button and select on div like this `<div style='position:relative'><select>
  <option>option 1</option>
  <option>option 2</option>
  <option>option 3</option>
</select>
<button>click</button></div>` @DavidPortabella

Comment: It's funny how is 2022 and it seems that we stil don't have a better way to solve this issue

Comment: @MuhammetCanTONBUL with all respect, how is this hack a perfect solution, exactly? For example, if I navigate to the button with the keyboard, it doesn't work. I strongly doubt any screen readers will appreciate this slight of hand. Even if that did work, setting it up is a pain since you need to use ugly absolute positioning to get the button to line up under the invisible select menu.

Comment: It's been almost 4 years and this just saved me XD

Comment: Any idea how to get a hover effect on the `<button>` with this technique?

Comment: @MattKleinsmith, I edited the style to get a :hover effect on the button. I used this as a reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54974024/how-to-make-hover-trigger-another-hover-in-css

Answer (score 41):

This is the closest I could get, change the size of the element onmouseover, and restore the size onmouseout:

```html
<select onMouseOut="this.size=1;" onMouseOver="this.size=this.length;">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: or

<SELECT onMouseOut="this.size=1;"  onMouseOver="this.size=this.length;">
...
</SELECT>

Comment: Also need to add onchange="this.size=1" so that the menu collapses as soon as selection is made. The element's CSS rules need to be configured as well.

Comment: It seems to work. The select width shrinks and then that causes a mouse out event reseting the select to it's original width. This causes a seizure effect. Setting a fixed width seems to fix it. With more than a few items the list expands past the view.

Comment: Don't do this if you have mobile visitors. Some popular smartphone browsers don't honour the size attribute, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43077171/size-not-working-for-select-option-in-mobile

Comment: Good solution for its simplicity. If you have more advanced needs, look at the solution provided by Caleb Hillary, which was the best for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68036061/5263950 . Another decent solution for those wanting to style their droplists is here: https://www.cssscript.com/select-styleable-dropdown-selectal/  It preserves some native look of the drop list. A basic setup is easy to configure, but does not allow proper keyboard navigation and  will kill the CSS styles or your droplist, although you can easily set them again by modifying the provided stylesheet.

Answer (score 8):

I think this is no longer possible in Chrome.

It seems version 53 of chrome disables this functionality as stated by Asim K T.

> According to the spec
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#trusted-events
>
> Trusted Events should not fire the default action (except click
>   event).

They have however enabled it in webview, but I have not tested this.

> We have found that some webviews are using fastclick inside them and
>   due to a risk of breakage we are going to allow mousedown on selects
>   even if they are untrusted.

And in this [discussion](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=520520) the idea to let developers open a dropdown programatically is abandoned.

Answer (score 7):

If any one is still looking for this :

```
<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
</select>
<br>
<button id="fire" type="button" >Show dropdown items</button>
```

Javascript:

```
var is_visible=false; 

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#fire').click(function (e) { 
    var element = document.getElementById('dropdown');


    if(is_visible){is_visible=false; return;}
    is_visible = true;

    var event;
    event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
    element.dispatchEvent(event);

    /* can be added for i.e. compatiblity.
      optionsSelect.focus();
       var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
       WshShell.SendKeys("%{DOWN}");
    */
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});


$(document).click(function(){is_visible=false; });
});
```

**Update:**

One till there is no perfect solution to this problem, But you can try to avoid this scenario. Why do you want to do this. i was wondering for a solution few months back to make a select plugin for mobile devices

https://github.com/HemantNegi/jquery.sumoselect

Finally ended up with masking the custom div (or any other element) with a transparent select element, so that it can directly interacts with user.

Comment: Plugins like https://github.com/HemantNegi/jquery.sumoselect are the only cross-browser solution that actually look better than the default control.

Comment: `iniMouseEvent` seems to work, but why does `$(select).trigger('mousedown')` doesn't work ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the best way I found. NOTE It only works with IE on Windows and your web would probably need to be in a secure zone - because we access the shell. The trick is that ALT-Down Arrow is a shortcut key to open a select drop down.

```
<button id="optionsButton" style="position:absolute;top:10px;left:10px;height:22px;width:100px;z-index:10" onclick="doClick()">OPTIONS</button>
<select id="optionsSelect" style="position:absolute;top:10px;left:10px;height:20px;width:100px;z-index:9">
    <option>ABC</option>
    <option>DEF</option>
    <option>GHI</option>
    <option>JKL</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function doClick() {
       optionsSelect.focus();
       var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
       WshShell.SendKeys("%{DOWN}");
   }
</script>
```

Comment: It won't work unless you do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/50215).

Comment: @Knu Internet Explorer automatically adds the ID's of elements as references to the element to the global scope.

Comment: @KlasMellbourn probably. They're trying to make their browsers more compliant now. Use the "size" solution mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is still looking for this,
This is how I solved it.

This is a solution based on the fact that the selection looks like it is expanded when the size in increased. We can increase size to make it look expanded. And reduce to make it seem closed. This way we can handle most use-cases by just having focus and blur listeners.

Select element needs to be absolutely positioned because increasing size will increase vertical height of element. If you have elements below, they will be pushed down if this is not done.

I have a wrapper code, that wraps the element and provides open and close methods.

Check this fiddle for usage: https://jsfiddle.net/10ar2ebd/16/

```
var SelectionWrapper = function(element, maxSize, selectCb) {

  var preventDefault = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }

  var isOpen = false;

  var open = function() {
    if (!isOpen) {
      element.size = maxSize;
      // Remove prevent default so that user will be able to select the option
      // Check why we prevent it in the first place below
      element.removeEventListener('mousedown', preventDefault);
            // We focus so that we can close on blur.
      element.focus();
      isOpen = true;
    }
  };

  var close = function() {
    if (isOpen) {
      element.size = 1;
      // Prevent default so that the default select box open behaviour is muted.
      element.addEventListener('mousedown', preventDefault);
      isOpen = false;
    }
  };

    // For the reason above
  element.addEventListener('mousedown', preventDefault);

    // So that clicking elsewhere closes the box
  element.addEventListener('blur', close);

    // Toggle when click
  element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (isOpen) {
      close();
      // Call ballback if present
      if(selectCb) {
                selectCb(element.value);
            }
    } else {
      open();
    }
  });


  return {
    open: open,
      close: close
  };
};

// Usage
var selectionWrapper = SelectionWrapper(document.getElementById("select_element"), 7, function(value) {
  var para = document.createElement("DIV");
  para.textContent = "Selected option: " + value;
  document.getElementById("result").appendChild(para);
});

document.getElementById("trigger").addEventListener('click', function() {
  selectionWrapper.open();
});
```

Comment: Excellent solution which should be much above in the stack. Tested as working with Brave (Chrome), Firefox, and even Internet Explorer 11. Pure Javascript, not requiring jQuery, nor any CSS. Elements preserve their original focusability and keyboard navigation, as well as their CSS styles. The SelectionWrapper() function can be used for different <select> drop lists. It is worth having a look at the code and demo at  the provide link on jsfiddle. The script must be placed after the <select> list(s) and the element that triggers the dropdown (not necessarily ab button).

Comment: I like you solution but see a small drawback: I want a thin drop list, but the dropmenu to expand to the width required by the options. Example:  for a regular `<select style="max-width:3em;">` the droplist widens automatically. But with the wrapped list, it does not and its width stays at 3em. Any patch?

Comment: The drop list seems not working on mobile Google Chrome on an Android smartphone, as tested with two devices. Can someone confirm? Any idea why and how to fix it? Working with Firefox mobile however.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution on https://jsfiddle.net/NickU/ahLy83mk/50/

It uses size="x" to open the dropdown while maintaining the dropdown and parent positions. The code also uses CSS styles to hide the right scroll area when it is not needed. I modified the code I found on stackoverflow, fixed the problems and added styling.

HTML:

```
<div>DIV example: <select id="dropdownDiv">
    <option value="Alpha">Alpha</option>
    <option value="Beta">Beta</option>
    <option value="Gamma">Gamma</option>
    </select>
</div>

<table id='tab1'>
<tr><td>Empty Cell</td></tr>
<tr><td> <select id="dropdown1">
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
    </select>
</td>
<tr><td><select id="dropdown2">
<option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="15">1</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option></select>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>Empty Cell</td></tr></table>
<br><button id="fire" type="button" onclick="openDropdown('dropdownDiv', this)" >Show dropdownDiv items</button>
<button id="fire" type="button" onclick="openDropdown('dropdown1', this)" >Show dropdown1 items</button>
<button id="fire" type="button" onclick="openDropdown('dropdown2', this)" >Show dropdown2 items</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
  var lastClosedElem = null;
  var maxItemsInDropDown = 12;
  function openDropdown(elementId, opener)
  {
     if (lastClosedElem !== null && lastClosedElem === opener)
     {
            lastClosedElem = null;
            return;
     }
     lastClosedElem = opener;
     
     function down()
      {
          var $this = $(this);

          var td = $this.closest('td,div');
          if (td && td.length > 0)
              td.height(td.height());

          var pos = $this.offset();
          var len = $this.find("option").length;
          if (len > 1 && len < maxItemsInDropDown)
          {
              $this.addClass('no-scroll');
              $this.addClass('noArrow');
          }
          else if (len > maxItemsInDropDown)
          {
              len = maxItemsInDropDown;
          }

          $this.css("position", "absolute");

          var _zIndex = $this.css("zIndex");
          if (!_zIndex)
              _zIndex = 'auto';
          $this.attr("_zIndex", _zIndex);
          $this.css("zIndex", 9999);

          $this.attr("size", len); // open dropdown
          $this.unbind("focus", down);
          $this.focus();
      }

      var up = function()
      {
          var $this = $(this);
          $this.css("position", "static");
          $this.attr("size", "1");
          $this.removeClass('no-scroll');
          $this.removeClass('noArrow');

          var _zIndex = $this.attr("zIndex");
          if (_zIndex)
          {
              $this.css("zIndex", _zIndex);
          }
          $this.unbind("blur", up);
          $this.unbind("click", upClick);
          $this.focus();
      }

      function upClick(e)
      {
          up.call(this);
          lastClosedElem = null;
      }

      $("#" + elementId).focus(down).blur(up).click(upClick).trigger('focus');
  }
```

CSS:

```
.no-scroll { cursor: pointer;}
.no-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {display:none;}
.no-scroll::-moz-scrollbar {display:none;}
.no-scroll::-o-scrollbar {display:none;}
.no-scroll::-google-ms-scrollbar {display:none;}
.no-scroll::-khtml-scrollbar {display:none;}


.noArrow {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
}


/* Cosmetic styles */
#tab1 tbody tr:nth-child(even) > td, div
{   background: linear-gradient( 180deg, #efefef 1%, #eeeeee 15%, #e2e2e2 85%); 
}
        
#tab1 tbody tr td
{   padding: 4px; 
}
        
#tab1
{   border: 1px solid silver; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Stop thinking that one thing is impossible, nothing is impossible to do, when you want to do.

Use this expand JS function created by a guy.

http://code.google.com/p/expandselect/

Include this JS and just call that passing the param as your select id, like that:

```
ExpandSelect(MySelect)
```

Comment: To be clear, that JS does *not* cause a `<SELECT>` to drop down.  As it explicitly states "Browsers do not allow expanding <select> in pure javascript, that control can be expanded only by directly clicking on it using the mouse".  So it *is* "impossible"!  Instead the JS states "We imitate expanded <select> control by creating another select with multiple options being displayed at once ..."  Which is quite different, and may or may not be acceptable for your usage case....

Answer (score 2):

You can use the new [`showPicker()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/showPicker) method:

```js
if ("showPicker" in HTMLSelectElement.prototype) {
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() { 
  document.querySelector('select').showPicker();
});
}
```

Comment: [Now supported on Firefox](https://web.dev/blog/web-platform-01-2024#htmlselectelementshowpicker) and all major browsers

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I don't believe that is possible with the default select box. You could do something with JS & CSS that achieves the desired result, but not (to my knowledge) the vanilla SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you asked for, but I like this solution for its simplicity. In most cases where I am wanting to initiate a dropdown, it is because I'm validating that the user has actually made a selection. I change the size of the dropdown and focus it, which nicely highlights what they've skipped:

```
$('#cboSomething')[0].size = 3;
$('#cboSomething')[0].focus();
```

Comment: Not sure why you got down-voted as it's not the "worst" way to do it. I would avoid this simply because it shifts the layout of surrounding elements. Though I think the solution from @CMS is more easily understood with the focus/blur events at the control.

Answer (score 0):

Opening an "HTML select" is possible through some workarounds mentioned in this question and similar ones. However a cleaner way of doing this is to add a select library to your project like "select2" or "chosen". 
For instance, opening a select2 programmatically would be as easy as:

```
$('#target-select').select2('open');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
select{
  overflow:hidden;
}
</style>

<select id="select">
  <option value="1">First option</option>
  <option value="2">Second second</option>
  <option value="3">Third option</option>
</select>

<script>
select.size = select.length;

select.onclick =()=> {
  select.size = 1;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if I'm fully understanding the question, but to open a dropdown, this simple approach worked for me.

You have an element:

```
<span onclick="openDropdown();">Open dropdown</span>
```

You have a dropdown:

```
<select class="dropdown">
    <option value="A">Value A</option>
    <option value="B">Value B</option>
    <option value="C">Value C</option>
</select>
```

And with JavaScript you can do the following:

```
document.querySelector('.dropdown').focus();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let elSelected = null;
function bindSelectClick(el){
    if(el.target !== elSelected){
        $(elSelected).trigger('blur');
        $(document).unbind('click', bindSelectClick)
    }
}

$('select.shared_date').on('focus', function (){
    // do something
    elSelected = this;
    $(document).on('click', bindSelectClick)

}).on('blur', function (){
    // do something
}).on('change', function (){
    // do something
})
```

Select does not lose focus after its menu is closed.
With a separate function, we check whether the click was on the select or elsewhere. If the elements are not equal, then you can fire some kind of event