# How to make a select field show list of options? - Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, focus

**I'm trying to mimic focus on a select field.**

e.g. When a user gains focus on a select field, the select field shows the options in a drop down list.

When using **$('select').focus()**, the options are not shown.

---

Any help on this one guys? =)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I open a dropdownlist using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360431/can-i-open-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery)

Answer (score 4):

Set the size attribute of the select to 6 (or whatever small int you like) on focus and back to 0 on blur.