# how to make the dropdownlist in expanded mode programatically in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, expand, mode

i have a dropdownlist on the page, now when user does not selects anything from it, and just hit the button, i displays a warning message, but i want to make the dropdownlist in the expanded mode, after the warning is displayed.Is it possible to make the dropdownlist in expanded mode in asp.net via code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not expand a Dropdown list from JavaScript neither on server side.
Here is a reference to similar question asked earlier [Old Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587757/force-asp-net-dropdownlist-to-expand)

But i did find a JavaScript hack for this which is given in the link below

[Expand html select element in javascript](http://www.gosu.pl/expand-html-select-element-in-javascript.html)

If this also dosent work out try some of the Jquery Plugins or AJAXControl toolkit Dropdown.