# keep dropdown list open in windows form

Tags: drop-down-menu, windows-forms-designer, toolstrip

How can keep the dropdown list open after the users click on one of the items? I'm working in windowsform with C# and my boss wants me to keep droplist open after users select one item form list. The dropdown list is inside a toolstrip, so it can be checked or unckecked by clicking on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can open a drop down list using jQuery . use this link to learn more , I think there is a way to open drop down list after it close.

[Can I open a dropdownlist using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360431/can-i-open-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery)