# Select and open a SELECT element from other event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I open a dropdownlist using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360431/can-i-open-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery)

Want to open a dropdown, on clicking on a textarea- is it possible?

I am currently trying in jquery-mobile, & want to open the SELECT-BOX in iPhone/Android device.

Here is my code-

JS:

```
function showScoopCategory()
{
    console.log('showScoopCategory');
    $('#scoopCategory').click();  // Not opening the dropdown
}
```

HTML:

```
<select id="scoopCategory" name="grievence">
    <option value="1">Option One</option>
    <option value="2">Option Two</option>
    <option value="3">Option Three</option>
</select>
...
<textarea id="scoopCategoryText" placeholder="Select & Open Dropdown" onClick="showScoopCategory();"></textarea>
```

Comment: Nope. Not the same.  Here want to open native Select-Box in iPhone/Android. - which should be a bit easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting focus()  to the SELECT element, is working in iPhone.

But at first, its opening the keypad for textarea, then it removes it & shows the Select box.

So, am planning to remove the textarea, and design a div like textarea there. So, onClick it will not open a keypad & it can directly open the Select-Box.

```
function showScoopCategory()
{
    console.log('showScoopCategory');
    $('#scoopCategory').focus();   // opening keypad, then removes it & opens Select box
}
```

Comment: & its worked. Changed the <textarea> to a <div> having similar design & change the focus to <select> on click on that <div>

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can open it like a normal click would.  However, you could increase the size of it.

```
$('#scoopCategoryText').on('focus', function() {
    var $sCategory = $('#scoopCategory'),    
        numCategories = $sCategory.find('option').length;

    console.log('showScoopCategory');
    $sCategory.attr('size', numCategories);          
}).on('blur', function() {
    $('#scoopCategory').attr('size', 1);
});
```

You could also make a mock dropdown with HTML and CSS, but getting it just right won't be quick and easy.

Comment: actually, its in Jquery mobile, and need to open the dropdown in native in iPhone & Android