# how open/close options of 'select' when you click on anyone 'div'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have open/close 'options' of 'select' on click anyone 'div' or 'button'.
How this done by javaScript or JQuery.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you post your html and your javascript so far?

Comment: This is no kind of understandable english. Please specifiy your question in a correct sentence!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I open a dropdownlist using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360431/can-i-open-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

If what you're asking is how to cause a drop-down `select` to drop down programmatically (e.g., in response to a click somewhere else that triggers your code), you can't do that.

Comment: You *can* cause a `select` to drop down using its `size` property. I've used it @ http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/8swnS/

Comment: @KooiInc: That's not dropping down drop-down select, that's changing a drop-down select into a non-drop-down select, with all of the layout implications that, er, implies. :-) (You're then handling the layout implications in your code and styling, but that's not the same thing.)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily simulate a click on an element, but a click on a `<select>` won’t open up the dropdown.

```
$('div').bind('click', function() {
     // code for open and close your select
});
```

Here the reference [Can I open a dropdownlist using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360431/can-i-open-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manipulate a `<select>` control, you can try using its `size` property. If its size is > 1, it will display options. Something along the lines of:

```
[somediv].onclick = function(){
  [someselect].size = 10;
}
```

Like T.J. Crowder rightfully remarked, this doesn't 'open' a dropdown, but it offers the possibility (using styling etc.) to simulate it.

Comment: That doesn't drop-down a drop-down select box, that turns a drop-down select box into a non-drop-down select box: http://jsbin.com/isikod Naturally you can play games with the styling and such, but to say that you can "open" it like that is misleading.