# Open dropdownlist (html.helper) with code

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is my drop down list:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("lstEndTimeEvent", new SelectList(new[] { "", "", "", ..., "" }) %>
```

It is closed, and it opens when I click on the arrow. How to make it to be opened on start?

Comment: This you check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8932866/7720  ?

Comment: you can make it a multi line select list by adding "MULTIPLE" Html attribute, and setting a visible CSS height like 150px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed was the size attribute.