# Is there a way to keep multiple select boxes open at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have 2 Select Box in my HTML page.

For some reason, I wish to want both the text boxes open at the same time.

This may be for several purposes, like taking screenshots of the both open at the same time.

The problem I face is, when I click on one selectbox, another goes away, when I click on the other, previous goes away.

Is it possible to keep both the selectboxes open at the same time?

I am fine if it requires javascript to do so.

Here are the two boxes, which I wish to keep open, is it possible to block some events or anything?

[image: For Example]
Thanks

Comment: you can sort of simulate it. Here are some approaches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360431

Comment: Simulating clicks doesn't work at all on selectboxes, firing a click event, may be via jquery, has no effect on select boxes, and that link didn't provide the solution but an alternative of removing selectboxes altogether

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@xiankai: Yes I have considered using a list view already, and then later instructing that this would/could be a combo-box. Here's my work with this modification.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your select box doesn't have many elements, have you considering using a listbox view instead? Simply add `multiple` to the your `<select>` element. Additionally, you can specify the height of the select box with the `size` attribute.