# Simulate click on select element with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I use this code for simulate `click` on `select` element:

```
$(function(){
   $("#click").click(function(){
       $("#ts").click();
       //$("#ts").trigger("click");
   });
});
```

and HTML code is:

```
<select id="ts">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">Lorem ipsum dolor s.</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="click" value="Click"/>
```

I test `click` and `trigger` but both not work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: and what do you want to happen?

Comment: A click event will NOT trigger the SELECT to open, if that's what you're hoping to do.

Comment: @Elen I want open select dropdown

Comment: as said above - it won't open select.... you can simulate `Enter` hit on `select`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360431/can-i-open-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery

Comment: @adeneo its change the size, I want open that. I edit the code but not work: http://jsfiddle.net/MANqK/3/

Comment: Triggering enter in a select box won't open it, just tried it [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/g3Ta3/1/)

Answer (score 35):

Well, you cannot attach `click` event to html `select` but you can do this tricky thing...

Take a look at here:

**Live DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/GR9jU/

Comment: Have'nt seen that one before, works for me, but something tells me it's not cross browser. +1 anyway.

Comment: It's working perfect in `chrome` let me see if I can do better for other browsers :-)

Comment: I'm guessing you'll need createEventObject for some browsers, but it will still probably have issues, and I don't think there's a way to do this that will work everywhere, at least I have'nt seen the createEvent method used much.

Comment: works for me. this is great! however it doesn't work on IE 7.

Comment: initMouseEvent() is depricated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/initMouseEvent

Comment: the Mozilla Developer network says the method MouseEvents.initMouseEvent() is deprecated [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/initMouseEvent) 
Any other solution ?

Comment: IE 9, doesn't work, IE 10 Doesn't work, IE 11 Doesn't work, FF most recent, doesn't work. do we have an alternative?

Answer (score 18):

This is the best cross browser method i think you can get. Tested on Safari, Firefox, Chrome and IE. <strike>For Chrome, Oscar Jara's answer is the way to go.</strike> *(update: 10-13-2016)*

```
$(function() {
    $("#click").on('click', function() {
        var $target = $("#ts");
        var $clone = $target.clone().removeAttr('id');
        $clone.val($target.val()).css({
            overflow: "auto",
            position: 'absolute',
            'z-index': 999,
            left: $target.offset().left,
            top: $target.offset().top + $target.outerHeight(),
            width: $target.outerWidth()
        }).attr('size', $clone.find('option').length > 10 ? 10 : $clone.find('option').length).change(function() {
            $target.val($clone.val());
        }).on('click blur keypress',function(e) {
         if(e.type !== "keypress" || e.which === 13)
            $(this).remove();
        });
        $('body').append($clone);
        $clone.focus();
    });
});
```

See [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vWx2H/456/)

Comment: I used this code tonight but had a few difficulties: the left and top lines both had to be offset for margins (using box-sizing:border-box if it matters).  The harder part was that I had set my select css to height:20px, which the regular select properly overrides for the drop down.  With this code it did not override.  Switching my css to min-height:20px was sufficient for my problem.  An hour of hair-pulling deserved to be shared :-)

Comment: it doesn't understand hiting enter in FF.

Comment: @Fanky Updated code and jsFiddle. Did it what you mean?

Answer (score 4):

This is as close as you'll get I think :

```
$(function(){
   $("#click").on('click', function(){
       var s = $("#ts").attr('size')==1?5:1
       $("#ts").attr('size', s);
   });
   $("#ts option").on({
       click: function() {
           $("#ts").attr('size', 1);
       },
       mouseenter: function() {
           $(this).css({background: '#498BFC', color: '#fff'});
       },
       mouseleave: function() {
           $(this).css({background: '#fff', color: '#000'});
       }
   });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/g3Ta3/4/)

Answer (score 2):

I ended up setting the selected attribute on the option itself.
Then triggering the change even on the select element.

Comment: thanks this was very useful ! $("#x").val('09.5');
$("#x").trigger("change");

Answer (score 0):

I have a complex `select` element, fed by the answer given in a previous `select` element. Options are fed by AJAX, triggered by `onchange` events.

For my needs, to prefill answers with a "hidden magic event" that simulates user behavior (in an intensive testing way) I use the following jQuery code in "my magic event". It selects the option by its index :

```
// Quick feed of my Car Form    
document.getElementById('carbrand').selectedIndex = 30; // "PORSCHE"
document.getElementById('carbrand').onchange();

var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function () {

    document.getElementById('model').selectedIndex = 1; // "911"
    document.getElementById('model').onchange();

    var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById('energy').selectedIndex = 1; // "SUPER"
        document.getElementById('energy').onchange();
    } , 200);

} , 200);
```

Merci à https://stackoverflow.com/users/1324/paul-roub pour les corrections ;-)

Answer (score -3):

little update(with `toggle`) for Oscar Jara variant

 http://jsfiddle.net/mike_s/y5GhB/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.