# How to open select menu using jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to open select menu using javascript/ jquery. Is this possible. Can createEvent in javascript is useful for this pus. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B9xv3/)

```
$('span').click(function(){
$('select').trigger('click')
})
```

Comment: Answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234971/simulate-click-on-select-element-with-jquery