# Simulate click on select box inside a div when div is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, select

A quick question. Can i simulate click on a select box (irrespective of the id or class of the selectbox) inside a div using JQuery. There is only one select box in the div. Thanks in advance

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="custom-select">
<select id="operator_select">
<option  value="1">1</option>
<option  value="2">2</option>
<select>
</div>
```

Jquery code that I tried:

```
    $(function(){
     $(".custom-select").click(function(){
       $('select',this).click();
       });
     });
```

here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/arjdev/5Sch2/

Comment: Are you trying to programatically open the drop-down menu? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234971/simulate-click-on-select-element-with-jquery

Comment: yes, i am tring that. @oGeez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    function open(elem) {
        if (document.createEvent) {
            var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            e.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            elem[0].dispatchEvent(e);
        } else if (element.fireEvent) {
            elem[0].fireEvent("onmousedown");
        }
    }

    $(".custom-select").click(function () {
        open($(this).find('select'));
    });
});
```

Your select tag is also not ended `</select>`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Sch2/1/)

Comment: have you tried it? it didnt work for me. can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Thanks, nice work.. I didn't think of going that far (creating a custom event).

Comment: Just a note, for me changing function name from `open` to something else `openSim` worked. Because open was opening new browser tab.

Answer (score 0):

try trigger method

```
 $(function(){
 $(".custom-select").click(function(){
   $('select').trigger( "click" );
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.. it will trigger on form load

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('.custom-select').find('select').trigger('click');
    });
```