# How to trigger select option using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cant find a way to just trigger select option to just show the dropdown list only. I know how to set a val for select but i just need to show the dropdown.

I want to just show the dropdown list, keep it open.

Comment: Please elaborate _just trigger select option_?

Comment: you want to trigger or to show dropdown?

Comment: If you mean you want to programmatically make a `select` element show the list of `option`, you can't. To do this you would need to use a select styling plugin.

Comment: @user3840211 See my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24754783/3834143

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Actually it is possible: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24754783/3834143

Comment: refer this So ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360431/can-i-open-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery

Comment: So did my answer not work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible with some tricky code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    open($('select'));
});

function open(elem) {
    if (document.createEvent) {
        var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        e.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        elem[0].dispatchEvent(e);
    } else if (element.fireEvent) {
        elem[0].fireEvent("onmousedown");
    }
}
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X2rAZ/)

From: [Simulate click on select element with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234971/simulate-click-on-select-element-with-jquery)