# expand select list on button click and hide select

Tags: javascript, html

I have a regular select list and I would like to:

1. Expand it on button, that is working and done
2. Keep hidden select list until the button is clicked.
3. I would like list options to be onclick event.

Any ideas and suggestions please?

```js
showDropdown = function (element) {
  var event;
  event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
  event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
  element.dispatchEvent(event);
};

window.runThis = function () { 
  var dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
  showDropdown(dropdown);
};
```

```html
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="Red">Red</option>
  <option value="Green">Green</option>
  <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
</select>
<br>
<button id="fire" type="button" onclick="runThis()">Show dropdown items</button>
```

Alternatively what is the best way of doing Select list that respond as spinner on adndroi and ios devices?

**UPDATE**

Let me update Question now as part of this is now working:

```
function get_tables_restaurant(){
        if($result2 = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM fandb_tables ORDER BY title ASC')){


  $return .= '<div class="lineheight"><button id="fire" type="button" class="add_table">+</button></div>
  <select id="dropdown">';
        while($r2 = $result2->fetch_object()){

        $return .= '<option value="'.htmlspecialchars($r2->title).'">'.htmlspecialchars($r2->title).'</option>';


        }
        $return .= '</select>';
        $return .= '<div id="test2" style="display: none;">
<h4>Table '.htmlspecialchars($r2->title).'</h4>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="area" size="50" value="'.htmlspecialchars($r2->area).'"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="tableno" size="50" value="'.htmlspecialchars($r2->title).'"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="title" size="50" value="1"/>
            <input type="submit" value="STARTER" class="starter"/>
        </form>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="area" size="50" value="'.htmlspecialchars($r2->area).'"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="tableno" size="50" value="'.htmlspecialchars($r2->title).'"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="title" size="50" value="2"/>
            <input type="submit" value="MAIN COURSE" class="maincourse"/>
        </form>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="area" size="50" value="'.htmlspecialchars($r2->area).'"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="tableno" size="50" value="'.htmlspecialchars($r2->title).'"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="title" size="50" value="3"/>
            <input type="submit" value="DESSERT" class="dessert"/>
        </form>
        <button onclick="$(\'#test2\').popup(\'hide\');" id="dismiss">DISMISS</button>
</div>';
        }
```

So now for each option I need to show popup which is `test2` id div with individual values as per above example.

I do get that this has to be inside the loop `while` however it than doesnt work at all as soon as I will place this `<div id="test2>...</div>` inside the loop.

Please can I ask you guys for advise?

**SORTED!**

:) as you said bit of reading and done:)

```
$( "#dropdown" ).change(function() {
      var element = document.getElementById('dropdown');
  $('#test2'+element.value).popup('show');
```

Thank you for everyones help:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `display: none` for the dropdown in CSS, and make a `.show` class with `display: inline-block` to be set to the dropdown when the button is clicked.

Have a look at jQuery's `.addClass()` and `.click()` functions for this.

EDIT: Using part of the answer [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13235219/2142071), I edited your jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sqp2xej5/13/

Comment: tried that, not sure what Im doing wrong: [https://jsfiddle.net/sqp2xej5/10/](https://jsfiddle.net/sqp2xej5/10/)

Comment: Perfect, now how do I merge this with option onclick function? I need to call `<option onclick="$(\'#test2\').popup(\'show\');">option1</option>` and that way it is not working

Comment: Inside `$(document).ready()` function, bind a function to the `click` event of the options. Have a look at jQuery's documentation on `click` event binding: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Im sorry Im completly blind on JS knowledge, trying to do this that way:
` $('#dropdown').change(function(){ 
    $(this).addClass('test2');
});` doesnt work is that the right way of thinking at least?

Comment: You want to call `$('#test2').popup('show')` when the value of the dropdown changes? Then inside the `.change()` function just call that. Either way, take some time to read the documentation (jQuery or Javascript in general) ;)

Comment: thanks, @Philip I have added `$( "#dropdown" ).change(function() {
  $('#test2').popup('show');
});` to the `$(document).ready(function()` and it is working fine.

I have updated my question if you dont mind looking into it for me please?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
showDropdown = function (element) {
  var event;
  event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
  event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
  element.dispatchEvent(event);
};

window.runThis = function () { 
  var dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
  showDropdown(dropdown);
};

$('#reload').click(function(){
  $('#dropdown').click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="Red">Red</option>
  <option value="Green">Green</option>
  <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
</select>
<br>
<button id="fire" type="button" onclick="runThis()">Show dropdown items</button>
<button id="reload" type="button">Hide dropdown items</button>
```

Comment: Hi Mondesliva, I mean I dont want to see select list at all just display options on button click? is that possible at all?

Comment: Sorry but I don't get you. Would you elaborate it more?