# Expose <select> element's options with JavaScript click()

Tags: javascript

I have 2 elements:

```
<span id="button" onmousedown="mouseDown()">Label</span>
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

I want to trigger the select element to show its list when I click the span element. I can only use JavaScript (no JQuery) to achieve this.

So far I have tried

```
mousedown function {
    var btn = getElementById("button");
    btn.nextSibling.click()
}
```

and:

```
mousedown function {
    function eventFire(el, etype){
      if (el.fireEvent) {
        el.fireEvent('on' + etype);
      } else {
        var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
        evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
        el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
      }
    }

    eventFire(btn.nextSibling, 'click');
}
```

But haven't been able to get it work.

If I do

```
mousedown function {
   console.log(btn.nextSibling);
}
```

This does return the right element, so I know my target is right. It's just not responding to `.click();` or the `eventFire` function.

Would anyone know why this is?

(I can include the rest of the mousedown function if need be, but it large and conplex and for the sake of this part, still works as a normal onmousedown)

Comment: What is this `eventname function { ... }` notation?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: I mean that's invalid JavaScript. So I assume it must be parsed by some framework or something?

Comment: [Here's the jQuery answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234971/simulate-click-on-select-element-with-jquery), which can naturally be adapted to use the DOM directly instead; [adeneo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13235144/157247) looks good.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click

Comment: ...and the linked dupetarget, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due, ...