# Trigger select tag with jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one question, when i want to triggering my label and my select tag, structure like this:

```
<label class="label"></label>
<select class="select">
</select>
```

and my jquery code:

```
$(".label").click(function(){
   $(".select").click();
});
```

i'm try to use `mousedown` too, but it still can't open the select tag...
Any idea ?

Comment: simulate on select won't open the drop down:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360431/can-i-open-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery

Comment: you can't open the drop-down programatically; you can only force focus onto the element. If you want to change it's physical appearance to dropped-down, you'll have to swap out the UI for another solution in HTML instead of the browser-UI for <select> element. Try a <ul> hooked up to a hidden <input>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
<label class="label" for='blabla'>my select</label>
<select class="select" id='blabla'>
</select>
```

Here is [the doc and exemples](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp)

edit: solution 2

```
<label class="label"></label>
<select class="select">
</select>
<script>
$('.label').click(function(){
   $('.select').attr('size', 3);
});
</script>
```

[exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/roine/eZMKd/)

Comment: i try the code above, but only triggering not opening select tag ...
Please help me ...

Answer (score 0):

`<label for="the_select">whatever</label><select id="the_select"></select>`

NB the 'for' on the label, which matches the id of the select. You don't need javascript if you use the label properly