# Once i click on label select button should get open

Tags: jquery, css

i want to open select button if i click on label ,

here is the code

```
<label>sachin</label>
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
```

is there any way in css or jquery ? i am not sure about this thing.

fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/Yh3Jf/

Comment: For now, we can't. The best solution will be to use jQuery dropdownlist to create your own dropdown list.

Goto http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360431/can-i-open-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery

Here there is some plugins which can help you
http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/

Comment: I don't think it's possible.  You can *focus* the select with the label, but it won't expand.  I think that's up to the OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to do something like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/Yh3Jf/6/

```
    <label id="l">sachin</label>
    <select id="s">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>        
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
   </select>  

$("#l").click(function () {
    var size = $('#s option').size();
    if (size != $("#s").prop('size')) {
        $("#s").prop('size', size);
    } else {
        $("#s").prop('size', 1);
    }
})
```

Comment: superb dude. Thats what i exactly want

Comment: if `$('#s option').size();` causes error use: `$('#s option').length;`

Answer (score 20):

No need for javascript here, just style it with CSS and use pointer events :

```
<label>
<select>
   <option value="0">Zero</option>
   <option value="1">One</option>
</select>
</label>
```

and the relative CSS is

```
label:after {
    content:'\25BC';
    display:inline-block;
    color:#000;
    background-color:#fff;
    margin-left:-17px;   /* remove the damn :after space */
    pointer-events:none; /* let the click pass trough */
}
```

Here is a ugly fiddle sample:  https://jsfiddle.net/1rofzz89/

Comment: this is awesome answer with no jQuery hacks

Comment: `pointer-events:none;` can solve a lot of problems, thanks for that.

Answer (score 6):

Wrong guys; to get the native selection-list just make a invisible clone under the mouse:

```
$("label").mouseover(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $input = $('#' + $(this).attr('for')); 
    if ($input.is("select") && !$('.lfClon').length) {
        var $clon = $input.clone();
        var getRules = function($ele){ return {
            position: 'absolute',
            left: $ele.offset().left,
            top: $ele.offset().top,
            width: $ele.outerWidth(),
            height: $ele.outerHeight(),
            opacity: 0,
            margin: 0,
            padding: 0
        };};
        var rules = getRules($this);
        $clon.css(rules);
        $clon.on("mousedown.lf", function(){
            $clon.css({
                marginLeft: $input.offset().left - rules.left,
                marginTop: $input.offset().top - rules.top,
            });
            $clon.on('change blur', function(){
                $input.val($clon.val()).show();
                $clon.remove();
            });
            $clon.off('.lf');
        });
        $clon.on("mouseout.lf", function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
        $clon.prop({id:'',className:'lfClon'});
        $clon.appendTo('body');
    }
});
```

Tested on IE10, Chrome 27 and Firefox 22

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Yh3Jf/24/

Comment: too aggressive, cloning a dom object has a lot of unexpected results

Comment: What unexpected results @Ayyash? Obviously you should test everything still works after implementing it. 

Regardless, If you want a less "aggressive" way you can always duplicate the <select> (with no [name]) in the HTML itself (without JS) and make the real select transparent and position it yourself using CSS for each case, but that takes more time/effort.

Comment: for example if you have another plugin to work with the same input, I remember I ran into a huge issue because my input file was attached to a plugin, my validation was cloning, (by using wrap()) and thus losing everything attached to the original element... in angular too if you do not clone in the right life cycle hook, you lose the control

Answer (score 3):

If you are just trying to gain focus on the select box (thus allowing you to arrow up and down), you can use something like...

```
<label for="sel">sachin</label>
<select id="sel">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Not the original question is about opening the select, this is just about getting control

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else is searching for this, I did this behavior by expanding the padding of the `<select>` tag, and making the label positioned absolute.

```
<div class="field-select">
  <label class="field-select__label" for="selector">Clickable Label</label>
  <select class="field-select__input" id="selector" name="selector">
    <option value="val1">value 1 </option>
    </option><option value="val2">Value 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

```
.field-select {
  position: relative;
}

.field-select__label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 5px;
  left: 0;
}

.field-select__input {
  padding: 50px 50px 20px 10px;
}
```

Check working example on [codepen](https://codepen.io/nouranology/pen/rNWapvL)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it inst possible to use any kind of code to have the native select dropdown show up.

But i have seen people use a backgrond image and then the select pops up (check Mightydeals.com)

If not resolve to jquery and some html to produce the effect.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem, my solution was in css with this line on the label :
pointer-events: none;
and it was alreadt with position: absolute;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).