# jQuery open select by button

Tags: jquery, select, triggers, click

How to open select dropdown by button?

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
   $('select').trigger('click');
});
```

My code: http://jsfiddle.net/UGkWp/

**UPDATE:**
I found solutions for webkit browsers, but only these browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/UGkWp/2/ Maybe You known how do this in each browsers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I open a dropdownlist using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360431/can-i-open-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery)

Comment: Your solution is on this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234971/simulate-click-on-select-element-with-jquery

Comment: Update, solutions for webkit browsers...

Comment: checkout http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#method-open

Answer (score 8):

You can do it with only CSS like this:

```
<html>
<body>

<div class="sorting">
<div class="sort right"><label>
<span>Items per page</span>
    <select>
    <option value="">Items per page</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
    <option value="60">60</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="200">200</option>
    </select>

    <span class="pointer"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span>
    </label>
    </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
<style>
select{
  -webkit-appearance:none;
    appearance:none;
      -moz-appearance:none;
}
.sorting{
    padding:5px 10px;
    border:1px solid #eee;
    clear:both;
  background:#FFF;
  height:40px;
}
.sorting h4{
    padding:4px 0 0;
    margin:0;
}
.sort{
    position:relative;  
    padding-left:10px;
  float:left;
}
.sort>label{
    font-weight:normal !important
}
.sort span.pointer{
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    border-left:1px solid #ddd;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    text-align:center;
    color:#c49633;
    font-size:20px;
    z-index:1;
}
.sort span.pointer i{
    margin-top:6px;
}
.sorting select{
    padding:5px 40px 5px 10px !important;
    margin-left:10px;
    border:1px solid #eee;
    background:none;
    height:30px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
</style>
```

Visit this fiddle for more details: https://jsfiddle.net/ssjuma/1mkxw2nb/1/

Comment: Adding a background colour to the select will hide the arrow

Comment: This solution is the best solution I've seen before, all of JavaScript and jQuery solution was failed, but your solution is exactly right.

Comment: I wouldn't not recommend copying this solution line for line. for accessibility best practices why would the caret be as the label content? it has no value to the label at all.

Answer (score 6):

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";
    $.fn.openSelect = function()
    {
        return this.each(function(idx,domEl) {
            if (document.createEvent) {
                var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
                event.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
                domEl.dispatchEvent(event);
            } else if (element.fireEvent) {
                domEl.fireEvent("onmousedown");
            }
        });
    }
}(jQuery));
$('#country').openSelect();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yqs90jdw/

Comment: This worked for me... the only addition I had to make, to get it to work in Safari, was to apply focus to the select before triggering the event. At the top of the `each` loop `$(domEl).focus();`

Comment: That jsfiddle example is not working anymore. Something has to changed.

Comment: Unfortunately initMouseEvent is now deprecated !
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/initMouseEvent

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have a look at this page:

[Can I open a dropdownlist using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360431/can-i-open-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery/360474#360474)

It seems like it is not possible to do this directly, but tools exists to emulate what you are trying to do.

An easy solution would be to use the "chosen"-plugin for jquery:
http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

This also gives you some great advantages over normal selects, and its easy to use.

On this you can simply fire a "mousedown" event like the following:

```
$('#dropdown_id_chzn').trigger('mousedown')
```

Given you have chosen (and jquery) enabled on your page the following code should do the trick:

HTML:

```
<select name="foo">
  <option value="1">Bar</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('select[name="foo"]').chosen();
$('#foo_chzn').trigger('mousedown');
```

Notice that chosen automatically appends the "_chzn" to your dropdown-name, which is what you should use in your selector

Answer (score 0):

hope this help

```
<select id="s">
    <option>aaaaa</option>
    <option>bbbbb</option>
    <option>ccccc</option>
</select>

<button>button</button>

$("button").click(function () {
    var size = $('#s option').size();
    if (size != $("#s").prop('size')) {
        $("#s").prop('size', size);
    } else {
        $("#s").prop('size', 1);
    }
})
```

Comment: if `$('#s option').size();` causes error use: `$('#s option').length;`

Answer (score 0):

I found a great solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18284923/8472295

In your case you can wrap the button in a label and apply the same solution.

HTML

```
<label for="orderby">
    <button type="button">
        <span>Sort</span>
    </button>
</label>
<select id="orderby" name="orderby" class="orderby" aria-label="Sort By">
    <option value="date" selected="selected">Latest</option>
    <option value="popularity">Popularity</option>
    <option value="rating">Average rating</option>
    <option value="price">Price: low to high</option>
    <option value="price-desc">Price: high to low</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
$("label").mouseover(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $input = $('#' + $(this).attr('for')); 
    if ($input.is("select") && !$('.lfClon').length) {
        var $clon = $input.clone();
        var getRules = function($ele){ return {
            position: 'absolute',
            left: $ele.offset().left,
            top: $ele.offset().top,
            width: $ele.outerWidth(),
            height: $ele.outerHeight(),
            opacity: 0,
            margin: 0,
            padding: 0
        };};
        var rules = getRules($this);
        $clon.css(rules);
        $clon.on("mousedown.lf", function(){
            $clon.css({
                marginLeft: $input.offset().left - rules.left,
                marginTop: $input.offset().top - rules.top,
            });
            $clon.on('change blur', function(){
                $input.val($clon.val()).show();
                $clon.remove();
            });
            $clon.off('.lf');
        });
        $clon.on("mouseout.lf", function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
        $clon.prop({id:'',className:'lfClon'});
        $clon.appendTo('body');
    }
});
```

Demo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Yh3Jf/24/

The js creates a clone of the select element which updates the original.

Tested and works for me, in my case I used it to hide the select field with css, then the button triggers a drop down where a selection can be made.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly don't need a two different elements to achieve this, if what you want it a button that on click, toggles open the options.

You only need a select element then you remove the drop arrow from the select element using css.

Check it out here

```css
.schedulAllselect {
    appearance: none;
 }
```

```html
<select id="" class="schedulAllselect">
  <option value="">SCHEDULE ALL</option>
  <option value="online" id="onlineOpt">Online Interview</option>
  <option value="offline" id="offlineOpt">Offline Offline</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -13):

I think this will help you..

[`Trigger documentation`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('select').trigger('click');
});

$('select').click(function(){
alert($(this).val());
});
```

Fiddle [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/UGkWp/5/)

Comment: using alert for open select is not correct, please think at first and then write