# opeining select option with mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to open the select without a mouseclick. I need on mousemove opening:

```
<select id="sel" onmouseover="???open the option list??" onmouseout="???close the option list??">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option> 
</select>
```

Also jquery's `$('#sel').trigger('mousedown');` doesn't work. I don't 
want `mousover="this.size=3" onmouseout="this.size=1".` Can somebody give a simple code?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432610/jquery-open-select-by-button, they are trying to tie it to a button, but the concept should be about the same.

Comment: I'm pushing back duplication indictments. I a long time searched solutions for it. No working solution cannot found, so i asked again.

Comment: Also a proverb says, that we are not hitting the questioner's mouth.

Answer (score 0):

[open dropdown list from javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19652085/open-dropdown-list-from-javascript-function)

[Is it possible to use JS to open an HTML select to show its option list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430237/is-it-possible-to-use-js-to-open-an-html-select-to-show-its-option-list)

[Can I open a dropdownlist using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360431/can-i-open-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery)

Looks like the answer is no.
Except if it only has to work in Chrome:

HTML

```
<select id="sel" class="dropdown">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option> 
</select>
```

JS

```
var dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown');
var event = new MouseEvent('mousedown');

dropdown.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Answer (score -3):

you can use jquery to handle it.

```
$( "div" ).mousemove(function( event ) {
  //do whatever you want
});
```

jquery works fine for me :)
https://api.jquery.com/mousemove/

Comment: Doesn't answer the question

Comment: why not? jquery works.