# Expand select dropdown

Tags: jquery

I am trying to expand a select dropdown upon clicking on a link.

```
<button type="button" id="btn">Click Me!</button> 
<select id='sel' name='sel'>
    <option>item 1</option>
    <option>item 2</option>
    <option>item 3</option>
    <option>item 4</option>
</select>
```

And the Javescript is as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function() {
       $("#sel").trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Any Ideas...??

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360431/can-i-open-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery

Comment: The answer is in the duplicate above. Change `$("#sel").trigger('click');` to `$("#sel").attr('size', 4);`

Comment: I do not want it to look like a select multiple box, but rather have the select dropdown, with the dropdown expanded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you programmatically tell an HTML SELECT to drop down (for example, due to mouseover)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot mimic native browser event using `.trigger`. Looking at [this link](http://learn.jquery.com/events/triggering-event-handlers/) to the jQuery tutorial it seems you need `.simulate` method from [jquery.simulate.js](https://github.com/eduardolundgren/jquery-simulate/blob/master/jquery.simulate.js). Moreover the open event of the dropdown box is given by `mousedown` not `click`.

**Update:** So the code become:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function() {
       $("#sel").simulate('mousedown');
    });
});
```

Comment: @Alepac Thank you for you answer, much appreciated. I did try that out. What am I doing wrong, link: http://jsfiddle.net/shawnfe/XE73h/

Comment: there was an error in my previous code, you need the `mousedown` event not the click, see my updated answer.

Comment: @Alepac I am still getting a proper outcome, please have a look a this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/shawnfe/XE73h/2/)

Comment: your jsfiddle works on my browser. Probably it's platform dependent issue, I use Chrome on linux, what do you use?

Comment: Awesome, I checked it out on Chrome it works perfectly :) I am using Mozilla 20.0.1. I did not see a result in Mozilla. I will look into it, thank you for your help..

Comment: Please put a comment about your investigation on mozilla to improve the answer

Comment: This doesn't work.  After including the file and linking to it properly, all I get is (".simulate is not a function).  Not sure how this got 14 upvotes.

Comment: Hey have tried a same example , also inlcuded the simulate js , still its not working !!!

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).simulate is not a function. Hmm, I already included the file into my project, but it did not work

Answer (score 2):

```
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/10844589/7926961
  function openDropdown(elementId) {
        function down() {
            var pos = $(this).offset(); // remember position
            var len = $(this).find("option").length;
                if(len > 20) {
                    len = 20;
                }

            $(this).css("position", "absolute");
            $(this).css("zIndex", 9999);
            $(this).offset(pos);   // reset position
            $(this).attr("size", len); // open dropdown
            $(this).unbind("focus", down);
            $(this).focus();
        }
        function up() {
            $(this).css("position", "static");
            $(this).attr("size", "1");  // close dropdown
            $(this).unbind("change", up);
            $(this).focus();
        }
        $("#" + elementId).focus(down).blur(up).focus();
    }
```

DEMO:

http://jsfiddle.net/XE73h/444/

Comment: Thanks, mate :-) -> made a slight modification to add mouse click and 'enter'-support: https://jsfiddle.net/slowy/pL0z0d7t/12/

Answer (score 0):

I thinks find to solve this problem i have test in ie, FF, chrome and Edge.

> ### HTML

```
<select id="selecttest">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">free</option>
    <option value="4">four</option>
    <option value="5">five</option>
    <option value="6">six</option>
    <option value="7">seven</option>
    <option value="8">height</option>
    <option value="9">nine</option>
    <option value="10">ten</option>
    <option value="11">eleven</option>
    <option value="12">twelve</option>
    <option value="13">thirdteen</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="testing" id="MyButton"/>
```

> ### JQUERY

```
$('#MyButton').on("click",function(){
    $("#selecttest").attr("size", 8);
    $("#selecttest").css("position","fixed");
    $('#MyButton').css("margin-left", $("#selecttest").width() + 5);});
$('#selecttest').on("change",function(){
    $("#selecttest").attr("size", 1);});
```

[jsfiddle test this](https://jsfiddle.net/ahcxg0x0/3/)

Answer (score -3):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function() {

    document.getElementById('sel').size='2'  
    });
});
```