# append more items to select when clicking on a particular option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with **select** menu on my html page *(bootstrap, jquery, js)*. On my requirement, the select menu (see the pictures below) should, at the first time show only `1,2,3` and others and if the user chooses `"others"` a sub menu should appeare on the same select menu allowing the user to choose `4` and `5` options without hiding the old menu.

[image]

[image]

I tried to do it with some Jquery code (by appending the `4` and `5` options when the user clicks on other option) the problem is the **select is closed when I choose the other option**.

```
<select name="mySelect">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="others">Others</option>
</select>

$(function(){
    $('select[name=mySelect]').on('change', function(){
        var selected = $(this).val();
        if(selected && selected == 'others'){
            $(this).children().last().remove();
            $(this).append('<option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option>');
            $(this).click();
        }
    });
});
```

How to disable the select `closing` when the user clicks on `"Other"` option?

Comment: Yes, there probably is. What have you tried? What went wrong? Where's the code of your attempts? Please take a read of the "*[mcve]*" and "*[ask]*" guidelines; and, if you haven't already, take the [tour].

Comment: @DavidThomas I tried to do it with some Jquery code (by on appending the 4 and 5 options when the user clicks on other option) the problem is the select is closed when I choose the other option. What I want to do is different, the select stay opend when the user clicks on other option. NB: I used the same code in the first response on my question (see bellow) thanks

Comment: So show that code, explain the problem(s) and why it didn't work.

Comment: @DavidThomas I used the same code in the first answer on my question ( see bellow) my problem is on how to disable the select closing.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're refusing, or otherwise unwilling, to show your code but rather than argue about that matter I've voted to close. Given that the code below is unlikely to work, you may wish to make that point in a comment to that answer. If your problem is "how to disable the select closing?" then you really should have asked that specific question.

Comment: @DavidThomas I updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

Fore example like this.
HTML:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="Others">Others</option>
</select>
```

JQuery:

```
$("select").change(function() {
  if($(this).val() == "Others") {
     $(this).append("<option value='5'>5</option>").find("option:selected").text("4").val("4");
  }
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/opMwvp

To disable closing the select, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16056763/8356159)

Comment: thanks for your reply. My problem is the select is closed when clicking on 'Other' option.

Comment: In this case, I think you could emulate the select with HTML and CSS. This way you can show/hide it whenever you like.