# Jquery click on another element and display select options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

at 1st kindly visit this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Y4LMX/

I was wondering is there a way to transfer the click? I meant, when I click on the green area ( `<div class="arrow"/>` ) in the meantime the wi`<select>` tag also get clicked, or selected and shows the options bellow. Is there a way to do this?

NB: I am doing this for IE supported `<select>` tag.

I tried with the following code:

```
$(".ie-arrow").click(function(){
     $(this).prev().find($("select").click());
});
```

but, It's not working. Can you solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Clicking a select programatically won't make it open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, following the Idea from answer no. two of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due), here is a solution: [Visit this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EgCW6/)

javascript:

```
$(".drop1").append("<div onclick='runThis1()' class='arrow'></div>");
$(".drop2").append("<div onclick='runThis2()' class='arrow'></div>");

(function () {
        showDropdown = function (element) {
            var event;
            event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
            element.dispatchEvent(event);
        };

        window.runThis1 = function () {
            var dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
            showDropdown(dropdown);
        };

        window.runThis2 = function () {
            var dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown2');
            showDropdown(dropdown);
        };
    })();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could see this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10844589/336542

A click on the select won't open it you have to change the size of it.

Answer (score 1):

You should try select dropdown plugins like dropkick.js

http://jamielottering.github.io/DropKick/

Answer (score 1):

I did it with size changing hack here: http://jsfiddle.net/f2Upx/

```
$(".drop1, .drop2").append("<div class='arrow' />");

$(".arrow").click(function(){
     $(this).prev().attr('size',5).css("height","200px")
            .parent().css("height","150px");
});
```

Also here's a simple example with fake selectbox I did couple of days ago http://jsfiddle.net/Jc2qq/ it would be easy to remake to suit needs of this question.

Comment: of course you need to attach an onblur event so that it returns to it's original size.

Comment: In cases like this smart idea is to do this with hidden input field and some div's to emulate selectbox.
So you don't have to do this in first place.

Comment: It's only increasing the size and I can't even close it. thank you.

Comment: save the original height and attach an onblur event to return the size and the height to the control.

Comment: It's just to give you basic idea, you can close it by adding blur event, returning css to default, and setting size to 1.

Comment: I need to do it with `<select>` tag