# Invoke click with javascript on element added with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

I want to fire off a click programmatically on an element added via AJAX.
How is that possible? This is makes it a bit of a special case because the element is not added to the due to being injected via AJAX.

Is there a proper way to achieve this?

Comment: are you using jQuery??

Comment: @Burki — That does the opposite to what is being asked

Comment: Okay, so you research: 1. Finding an element in the DOM, and 2. Programmatically firing a click at it. This ground is **extremely** well-covered, what have you found, and how have you tried to use it?

Comment: Being added by Ajax shouldn't make a difference. If it is in the DOM then it is in the DOM, and you (probably) aren't trying to access it before then. You'll need to provide a proper test case: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Burki — The question is asking how to trigger an event, not how to listen for one.

Comment: @Burki: OP wants to *fire* a click, not respond to it. (And there's no indication they're using jQuery.)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809057/how-do-i-programmatically-click-on-an-element-in-firefox. It shouldn't matter if the element was added dynamically.

Comment: Solution was found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500542/jquery-click-on-another-element-and-display-select-options.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and you can achieve that in to steps:

1. Attach the event by `event-delegation` to the elements added by AJAX:

   `$('#wrapper').on('click', '.element', function() {
       // Add your functionality here
   });`
2. Trigger the click programmatically:

   `$('.element').trigger('click');`

The click will work now because you attach it by `event-delegation` on the first step. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

do this

jquery:

```
$('#parent').on('click','#element',function(){
 alert('clicked');
});
```

javascript:

```
document.getElementById("parent").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if(e.target && e.target.id== "element") {
        alert('clicked');
    }
});
```

Learn more about event delegation

Note `#element` is the id of your element,you can change `#parent` with the closest tag that is not added by the ajax

Comment: This listens to the event. It does not fire it :-)

Comment: then do `document.getElementById("element").click()`

Comment: It would work if the element was not added via ajax.