# How to activate the dropdown menu of the select element via keyboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select element in my HTML:

```
<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
</select>
```

It renders as a drop-down menu, which, when the user clicks it, (surprise!) drops down.
In order for the page to be used via keyboard only, I wish to make it so that the menu drops down when the user presses a key.

```
$('body').keypress(function(event) {
    var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
    if (key == 'a') {
        $('#dropdown').doSomething(); // ?
    }
});
```

The best I've found is to invoke `focus()`.  It allows to select the value via keyboard, but it doesn't drop down the menu.  Is there a way to make the menu drop down?

Comment: Not sure if this is possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360431/can-i-open-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery -- There's always a few other threads trying, but it always seems to come up empty.

Comment: AFAIK Not possible. Selects need the direct user interaction. Although you can fake your select box using standard elements

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you programmatically tell an HTML SELECT to drop down (for example, due to mouseover)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430237/is-it-possible-to-use-js-to-open-an-html-select-to-show-its-option-list

Comment: Thank you all for quick responses, I didn't find out this question was already answered by cursory search before asking.

Comment: If all you want is to allow keyboard navigation, all major browsers support expanding the dropdown. Alt + down arrow works on Firefox and supposedly IE, Enter or Space on Chrome and other Webkit browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Using Chrome browser (28.0) you can force a mouse event like this:

```
var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
e.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
$("#dropdown").get(0).dispatchEvent(e);
```

**[See this working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nSQdJ/)** do not forget to click on body before pressing 'a' to give focus to it