# Trigger select dropdown on button click in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have the following code for a button in jQuery Mobile

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="toolbar-icons">
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" style="margin-left:15px;">
        <a href="#" data-icon="flat-mail" data-theme="a" data-iconpos="notext" data-role="button">Yes</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was wondering if it would be possible to trigger a `select` dropdown by clicking this button?
Is there anyway of doing it?

Cheers

Comment: Do you want to trigger change event or just changing selected value?

Comment: If you mean show the options of a `select` element, no there is no way to do that programamtically.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360431/can-i-open-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery

Comment: See http://plnkr.co/edit/H9eVED6b7KnIEYM9pcTW?p=preview