# click on <select> dropdown doesn't work when clicking on the label of the object

Tags: html, css

I have a  dropdown, which works fine. It has a text label on it (i.e., the current selection). When I click on the  object on or near the text, the dropdown doesn't open; if I click on the object but further from the text, it does open. I want it to open if I click on it anywhere. Cleared CSS etc. and that didn't help.

Sorry, as this is obviously some sort of rookie mistake... :)

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Please add your code Here and if it is possible try to replicate the problem in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I think you're expecting functionality that isn't supposed to be there.

Comment: See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360431/can-i-open-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery) for further details as to why what you're looking for doesn't work and an array of workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help
[code](http://jsfiddle.net/ppollono/LRT8F/)

```
<label for="select">
    label
</label>
<select id="select">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.