# Dropdown on ajax page shutting

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

So I have a div that I refresh the contents of every 1 second.
The content being loaded has a dropdown on the page.
The dropdown closes itself every time it refreshes(Expected).

How should I handle this so that the dropdown stays open?

JS

```
    var isRefreshing = false;
    var refreshInterval;
    function initRefresh(page, refreshRateMs) {
        if (!isRefreshing) {
            refreshInterval = setInterval(function () { refreshPage(page) }, refreshRateMs);
            isRefreshing = true;
        }
    }
    function refreshPage(page) {
        $.get(page, function (data) {
            $("#content-wrapper").empty().append(data);
        });
    }
```

Page loading

```
<select id="teamSize" name="teamSize" class="input-xlarge">
    <option value="5">
        5
    </option>

    <option value="4">
        4
    </option>

    <option value="3">
        3
    </option>

    <option value="2">
        2
    </option>

    <option value="1">
        1
    </option>
</select>
<script>
    initRefresh('/lobby', 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Move the div outside the area you are refreshing.
2. After refreshing simulate a click on the dropbox. This question may
   help:
   [Can I open a dropdownlist using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360431/can-i-open-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery)