# How to manually toggle angular-ui-select dropdown (SINGLE Select)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

My issue is same with question [How to manually toggle angular-ui-select dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741519/how-to-manually-toggle-angular-ui-select-dropdown#), but in my case, i just use single select feature.

Generally, I'm using AngularUI's ui-select to create single select on a page. I need to be able to open the dropdown list when a user clicks on a button on the page.

I've tried using jQuery's `.click()`, `.trigger('click')` but they're not working.

This plunker has been forked with Singe Select Option:

> http://plnkr.co/edit/0OKTgpURgAk7CCG0GIxC?p=preview

How can I toggle the dropdown manually, from outside the ui-select element's context?

**Update:**

- In this plunker (plnkr.co/edit/7wXP6cSqPaDlvhEbkNau?p=preview), the version of ui-select is 0.9.x, they use the button to active the event, and we can use `$("#"+attrs.openMenuByClick).find('button').click();`
  (Thank @sdfacre for this help)
- The new version of ui-select is 0.13.2, they use the `<span>` instead `<button>`, so how can I call ng-click function when they use `<span>` without using directive?

> http://plnkr.co/edit/0OKTgpURgAk7CCG0GIxC?p=preview

Comment: I think it would be good if you could edit your question to include the additional info present in the other question, just so it clearly stands by itself.

Comment: Hi @ajshort, the option is just changed from muliselect to single select. I have edited the question and put more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like with single select, the toggle control is on a button not an input.

so, try this

```
$("#"+attrs.openMenuByClick).find('button').click();
```

plunker is also available here http://plnkr.co/edit/r2Iufl9CcNRV6iozvWQj?p=preview

Comment: It's not work. Did you test yourself on plunker and that worked?

Comment: interesting, I did test this on plunker. Anyway, sorry about that, I will paste the plunker link here later.

Comment: I might somehow mixed up something when I was testing it. I have fixed the answer and provided the link to plunker. please check. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you. It works.

But sorry so much, I didn't check the version of ui-select library when fork the plunker. In that plunker, version of library is 0.9.x. My real issue is on version 0.13.2. Sorry, it's my fault.

I have updated the plunker on http://plnkr.co/edit/0OKTgpURgAk7CCG0GIxC?p=preview. Could you take a look for me again?

Comment: No problem. Your new plunker works for me, what would you like me to look exactly?

Comment: Sorry, that issue is resolved. But without directive, can we trigger the ui-select? I have updated the plunker with example when we do not use directive: plnkr.co/edit/0OKTgpURgAk7CCG0GIxC?p=preview.

Comment: I don't see why you can't do that without directive. having a directive is just to make life easier if you have this requirement in multiple places. you can even implement this in a separate javascript function outside of angular. there are many ways to achieve this, you just pick what suit you the best.

Comment: Yes, we can use directive to resolve this issue. But if you take a look at my  plunker, you can see we can not trigger ui-select without using directive. I so curious about the reason.

Comment: I already tried it, The trigger button works for me. could it be a browser issue?

Comment: I don't know why it failed when I tested =.=' It works now. Thank so much, sdfacre