# How can i open the drop-down using jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

I am using Phonegap and Bootstrap. How can I open this `select` using jQuery?

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-width="100%" name="selValue" id="msg_counts_id">
    <option value="" >select</option>
    <option value="1">You</option>
    <option value="2">Are</option>
    <option value="3">my...</option>
</select>
```

Comment: When you want to open this select box

Comment: It's not possible with native browser select.

Comment: i think you are asking something like before asked please check link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360431/can-i-open-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery" will help you to understanding.

Comment: Hi, i am using custom drop-down image.so, if i click the img tag the corresponding selection drop want to open.