# R Shiny Dropdown on hover

Tags: css, r, twitter-bootstrap, shiny

Is there a simple package/CSS script that allows the selectInput() to display the drop-down contents **on over** instead of **on click**.

Been doing some research and it seems like this is not possible because the functionality is rendered by the browser. The only option may be to create a custom ul element using HTML and adding CSS to this. Is this the only way?

Is the twitter bootstrap package appropriate for this problem? Been having trouble finding good examples of the methods described in this package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to make native select to open on *hover*, but there are better options.

Yes, twitter bootstrap is a viable option if you are already using it or have planned or researched about it.

Use [select2](https://select2.org) and see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809145/activate-select-menu-on-hover-mouseover-using-select2) how can you open it on *hover* using simple jQuery.

---

Here's HTML5's native way:

```html
<select onMouseOut="this.size=1;" onMouseOver="this.size=this.length;">
    <option>Option Value 1</option>
    <option>Option Value 2</option>
    <option>Option Value 3</option>
    <option>Option Value 4</option>
    <option>Option Value 5</option>
    <option>Option Value 6</option>
    <option>Option Value 7</option>
</select>
```

Comment: select2 may be a good idea but getting jquery to integrate with R Shiny can get complicated!

Comment: You are right. I haven't looked into shiny much. I think you can start a bit and then post, you'll get a lot of help here.

Comment: Whats the native way to do it?

Comment: I've added the native way in my answer. But I guess It'll only be helpful if you wanted to customize the package.

Comment: It works, but like you said there are probably better ways of doing it for aesthetic reasons.