# How to show select dropdown using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have button and a select box. i want to open the dropdown by click on the button.

```
<button id="showDropdown"></button>
<select id="selectME">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

**I have tried this js script:**

```
$("#showDropdown").click(function(){
  $("#selectME").click(); 
});
```

This is not working for me. Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I open a dropdownlist using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360431/can-i-open-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery)

Comment: May be that article will help you https://medium.com/browserquirks/browserquirk-programmatically-opening-a-select-box-4ca745a8468f

Comment: Try using select2 jQuery plugin and trigger open event on click.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the `<select>` element, append it to the `body` and show it.

```js
$('#showDropdown').click(function(){
  var select = $('#selectME');
  
  var clone = select.clone().removeAttr('id');
  
  clone.val(select.val()).css({
      overflow: 'auto',
      position: 'absolute',
      left: select.offset().left,
      top: select.offset().top + select.outerHeight(),
      width: select.outerWidth()
  });
        
  clone.attr('size', clone.find('option').length)
  
  clone.change(function() {
      select.val(clone.val());
  });
        
  clone.on('click blur keypress',function(e) {
   if(e.type !== 'keypress' || e.which === 13)
      $(this).remove();
  });
  
  clone.appendTo('body').focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="showDropdown">Select me</button>
<select id="selectME">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is not showing like the normal dropdown on firefox. but it open the options.