# Is it possible to use JS to open an HTML select to show its option list?

Tags: javascript, html-select

Is it possible to use JavaScript to open an HTML select to show its option list?

Comment: What's the need for this functionality, btw? Just curious...

Comment: One reason this would be good is to support keyboard shortcuts (which a lot of sites do these days, e.g. Twitter, GitHub, G+).

Comment: You can use your keyboard to open select fields already. Typically, (it depends on your browser) you tab to the field and then press the down or up arrow to open the select and scroll through the options.

Comment: @DarrylHein, up and down arrows do not work for my dropdown in my datatable....I wish they did, I have been trying to assign the arrows to the function, if a function existed...

Comment: Wouldn't this be useful to say, have the select element open when any of the parent element div is clicked rather than the select element itself?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Unfortunately there's a simple answer to this question, and it's "No"

Comment: sure about that?

Comment: Can't be done (with plain html/javascript)

Comment: I am also wishing I could programmatically open a select for keyboard users. In Firefox the change event doesn't fire until the select loses focus, and if the menu isn't actually open, it doesn't select anything when you tab off. LAME-O!

Comment: this not the correct answer for this question
the following link will give you the answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due

Comment: Technically this answer is correct, it's not possible. But if you want to make it seem like you did look at the answer further down: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1489537/151503

Comment: check here http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/GR9jU/ working example

Comment: @Amit it doesn't work in FF

Comment: @Amit doesn't work (anymore) in Chrome (using v55)

Comment: Most accurate to say there isn't a well-supported method amongst all the major browsers (as of 2017-04-19). @Asaf David did provide a method that works in FireFox so it's clearly possible in a non-insignificant number of use-cases.

Comment: Thanks for the TLDR :)

Comment: Are you aware of any context around this? Is it disallowed for some security reason? Did a standard for implementing it fail to coalesce? Is it technically impossible because of some obscure technical limitation? In other words, just, *why*?

Comment: Not a helpful answer without any explanation.

Comment: Please check:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due/69569729#69569729 It uses size="x" to open the dropdown while maintaining the dropdown and parent positions. The code also uses CSS styles to hide the right scroll area when it is not needed.:

Comment: Nops !!! It's possible try use select2 plugin, using the open method https://select2.org/programmatic-control/methods

Comment: @Marinpietri The "select2 plugin" that you mention isn't an HTML select as the question asks. Instead it requires replacing the whole select with a custom Javascript-driven widget.

Answer (score 41):

I had this problem...and found a workable solution.

I didn't want the select box to show until the user clicked on some plain HTML. So I overlayed the select element with `opacity=.01`. Upon clicking, I changed it back to `opacity=100`. This allowed me to hide the select, and when the user clicked the text the select appeared with the options showing.

Comment: Isn't that just hiding/showing the actual select field? The question is about showing/opening the options list.

Comment: My method does show show/open the options list along with the select box itself. The only way to open the options list is to have the select box clicked. Which I accomplished by invisibly overlaying the select on top of some target text.

Comment: This was the only solution capable of styling the select menu button in the buggy WebView of Android. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, was looking for this for a couple of hours. This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but it DOES present a workaround for the case where you want to style a <select> element while still providing the native control, which is a reason why you might want to open the options drop down using js.

If you set the opacity of the <select> to 0, when the user clicks the invisible select, the drop down of options will appear as normal.

Comment: Phil or @ChrisSnyder, providing a working jsfiddle would be nice. Also, does the user have to actually click (I expect that's what most readers here want to avoid) or can it be simulated/triggered another event? My goal is to have a dropdown "instagrow"--show its effect immediately--upon choosing a "Show more options..." row at the end of the list.

Comment: yes, I'm not sure how it solves the original question, can you provide a code sample? Thanks!

Comment: This works beautifully on mobile; far better than the rather Stone Age standard dropdown. I used a full-screen div for the underlay element, placed a full-screen image inside it, added a title with absolute positioning then laid the select on top of that, also with absolute positioning and 100% width/height so the user can tap anywhere on it. The list pops up over the image. Very satisfying.

Answer (score 29):

I use this... but it requires the user to click on the select box...

Here are the 2 javascript functions

```
function expand(obj)
{
    obj.size = 5;
}
function unexpand(obj)
{
    obj.size = 1;
}
```

then i create the select box

```
<select id="test" multiple="multiple" name="foo" onFocus="expand(this)" onBlur="unexpand(this)">
<option >option1</option>
<option >option2</option>
<option >option3</option>
<option >option4</option>
<option >option5</option>
</select>
```

I know this code is a little late, but i hope it helps someone who had the same problem as me.

ps/fyi 
i have not tested the code above (i create my select box dynamically), and the code i did write was only tested in FireFox.

Comment: +1, done similar things before, I believe I also set it's position to absolute when it was expanded so it didn't break document flow, and back to block when it was collapsed.

Comment: Hey thanks Chad,
Your comments just helped me solve an issue!
Wish i could +1 you back ;)

Comment: In my case it wouldn't solve the problem exactly, but it would be an option. +1

Comment: @DarrylHein: In this case, it's not just ___an__ option_, it's 5 `<option>`s ...

Comment: very crafty, thanks.

Answer (score 28):

This works on Google Chrome

```
dropDown = function (elementId) {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById(elementId);
    try {
        showDropdown(dropdown);
    } catch(e) {

    }
    return false;
};

showDropdown = function (element) {
    var event;
    event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
};
```

Comment: FYI: It did work for me on Chrome 35.0.1916.153   Make sure you're passing the actual element and not a jQuery obj.

Comment: This works on latest Chromium-based Opera too.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is now deprecated on [Chrome 53+](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5718803933560832)

Comment: It didn't work for me on PC/Mac, but it works on mobile (and you need to add a mouseup event as well).

Comment: Not working with Chrome 59 on Windows.

Comment: not working anymore on chrome. still working on safari.

Comment: this will no longer work.  Can't send a mouse down event to a select element.

Answer (score 5):

After trying to solve this issue for some time, I managed to come with a working solution that is also valid:

```
var event = new MouseEvent('mousedown');
element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

I've tried to implement this in Jquery as well, using `trigger` and `mousedown` or only `mousedown` but with no success.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Firefox 50.

Comment: Not working with Chrome 59 on Windows. Does work with FireFox 51 on Windows though.

Answer (score 4):

This is very late, but I thought it could be useful to someone who needs it.
The below JS will solve this problem.

```js
<script>     
    $(document).ready(() => {
        document.getElementById('select').size = 3
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Slight different because that will adjust that actual size of a select, not show all the select values. If you only have, as in your example, 3 options, then that wills show all of them, but it will also adjust the layout of your page.

Comment: ~Rhys thanks! this lead me to more ideas. Try this out, it will set to the exact height needed for the select controls. $("select:visible").each(function(i,e){e.size=e.length;});

Comment: Not a good idea. Setting the size on a select element changes it from being a dropdown list to a listbox (using windows controls terminology). The problems this brings is that you have to look after the dropdown now including placement (it doesn't float above the page like a true dropdown), closing (if the user clicks elsewhere the list remains visible). I wasted much time playing with size. An mobile safari seems to ignore it anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly certain the answer is: No. You can select options with JavaScript but not open the select. You'd have to use a custom solution.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I present is safe, simple and compatible with Internet Explorer, FireFox and Chrome.

This approach is new (2014) and complete. I not found nothing equal to that solution on the internet. Is simple, cross-browser (Internet Explorer, Chrome and Firefox), preserves the layout, use the select itself and is easy to use.

Note: JQuery (jquery-1.3.2) is required.

**HTML CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>CustonSelect</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./CustomSelect.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="testDiv"></div>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select id="Select0" >
                    <option value="0000">0000</option>
                    <option value="0001">0001</option>
                    <option value="0002">0002</option>
                    <option value="0003">0003</option>
                    <option value="0004">0004</option>
                    <option value="0005">0005</option>
                    <option value="0006">0006</option>
                    <option value="0007">0007</option>
                    <option value="0008">0008</option>
                    <option value="0009">0009</option>
                    <option value="0010">0010</option>
                    <option value="0011">0011</option>
                    <option value="0012">0012</option>
                    <option value="0013">0013</option>
                    <option value="0014">0014</option>
                    <option value="0015">0015</option>
                    <option value="0016">0016</option>
                    <option value="0017">0017</option>
                    <option value="0018">0018</option>
                    <option value="0019">0019</option>
                    <option value="0020">0020</option>
                    <option value="0021">0021</option>
                    <option value="0022">0022</option>
                    <option value="0023">0023</option>
                    <option value="0024">0024</option>
                    <option value="0025">0025</option>
                    <option value="0026">0026</option>
                    <option value="0027">0027</option>
                    <option value="0028">0028</option>
                    <option value="0029">0029</option>
                    <option value="0030">0030</option>
                    <option value="0031">0031</option>
                    <option value="0032">0032</option>
                    <option value="0033">0033</option>
                    <option value="0034">0034</option>
                    <option value="0035">0035</option>
                    <option value="0036">0036</option>
                    <option value="0037">0037</option>
                    <option value="0038">0038</option>
                    <option value="0039">0039</option>
                    <option value="0040">0040</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select id="Select1" >
                    <option value="0000">0000</option>
                    <option value="0001">0001</option>
                    <option value="0002">0002</option>
                    <option value="0003">0003</option>
                    <option value="0004">0004</option>
                    <option value="0005">0005</option>
                    <option value="0006">0006</option>
                    <option value="0007">0007</option>
                    <option value="0008">0008</option>
                    <option value="0009">0009</option>
                    <option value="0010">0010</option>
                    <option value="0011">0011</option>
                    <option value="0012">0012</option>
                    <option value="0013">0013</option>
                    <option value="0014">0014</option>
                    <option value="0015">0015</option>
                    <option value="0016">0016</option>
                    <option value="0017">0017</option>
                    <option value="0018">0018</option>
                    <option value="0019">0019</option>
                    <option value="0020">0020</option>
                    <option value="0021">0021</option>
                    <option value="0022">0022</option>
                    <option value="0023">0023</option>
                    <option value="0024">0024</option>
                    <option value="0025">0025</option>
                    <option value="0026">0026</option>
                    <option value="0027">0027</option>
                    <option value="0028">0028</option>
                    <option value="0029">0029</option>
                    <option value="0030">0030</option>
                    <option value="0031">0031</option>
                    <option value="0032">0032</option>
                    <option value="0033">0033</option>
                    <option value="0034">0034</option>
                    <option value="0035">0035</option>
                    <option value="0036">0036</option>
                    <option value="0037">0037</option>
                    <option value="0038">0038</option>
                    <option value="0039">0039</option>
                    <option value="0040">0040</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select id="Select2" >
                    <option value="0000">0000</option>
                    <option value="0001">0001</option>
                    <option value="0002">0002</option>
                    <option value="0003">0003</option>
                    <option value="0004">0004</option>
                    <option value="0005">0005</option>
                    <option value="0006">0006</option>
                    <option value="0007">0007</option>
                    <option value="0008">0008</option>
                    <option value="0009">0009</option>
                    <option value="0010">0010</option>
                    <option value="0011">0011</option>
                    <option value="0012">0012</option>
                    <option value="0013">0013</option>
                    <option value="0014">0014</option>
                    <option value="0015">0015</option>
                    <option value="0016">0016</option>
                    <option value="0017">0017</option>
                    <option value="0018">0018</option>
                    <option value="0019">0019</option>
                    <option value="0020">0020</option>
                    <option value="0021">0021</option>
                    <option value="0022">0022</option>
                    <option value="0023">0023</option>
                    <option value="0024">0024</option>
                    <option value="0025">0025</option>
                    <option value="0026">0026</option>
                    <option value="0027">0027</option>
                    <option value="0028">0028</option>
                    <option value="0029">0029</option>
                    <option value="0030">0030</option>
                    <option value="0031">0031</option>
                    <option value="0032">0032</option>
                    <option value="0033">0033</option>
                    <option value="0034">0034</option>
                    <option value="0035">0035</option>
                    <option value="0036">0036</option>
                    <option value="0037">0037</option>
                    <option value="0038">0038</option>
                    <option value="0039">0039</option>
                    <option value="0040">0040</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select id="Select3" >
                    <option value="0000">0000</option>
                    <option value="0001">0001</option>
                    <option value="0002">0002</option>
                    <option value="0003">0003</option>
                    <option value="0004">0004</option>
                    <option value="0005">0005</option>
                    <option value="0006">0006</option>
                    <option value="0007">0007</option>
                    <option value="0008">0008</option>
                    <option value="0009">0009</option>
                    <option value="0010">0010</option>
                    <option value="0011">0011</option>
                    <option value="0012">0012</option>
                    <option value="0013">0013</option>
                    <option value="0014">0014</option>
                    <option value="0015">0015</option>
                    <option value="0016">0016</option>
                    <option value="0017">0017</option>
                    <option value="0018">0018</option>
                    <option value="0019">0019</option>
                    <option value="0020">0020</option>
                    <option value="0021">0021</option>
                    <option value="0022">0022</option>
                    <option value="0023">0023</option>
                    <option value="0024">0024</option>
                    <option value="0025">0025</option>
                    <option value="0026">0026</option>
                    <option value="0027">0027</option>
                    <option value="0028">0028</option>
                    <option value="0029">0029</option>
                    <option value="0030">0030</option>
                    <option value="0031">0031</option>
                    <option value="0032">0032</option>
                    <option value="0033">0033</option>
                    <option value="0034">0034</option>
                    <option value="0035">0035</option>
                    <option value="0036">0036</option>
                    <option value="0037">0037</option>
                    <option value="0038">0038</option>
                    <option value="0039">0039</option>
                    <option value="0040">0040</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select id="Select4" >
                    <option value="0000">0000</option>
                    <option value="0001">0001</option>
                    <option value="0002">0002</option>
                    <option value="0003">0003</option>
                    <option value="0004">0004</option>
                    <option value="0005">0005</option>
                    <option value="0006">0006</option>
                    <option value="0007">0007</option>
                    <option value="0008">0008</option>
                    <option value="0009">0009</option>
                    <option value="0010">0010</option>
                    <option value="0011">0011</option>
                    <option value="0012">0012</option>
                    <option value="0013">0013</option>
                    <option value="0014">0014</option>
                    <option value="0015">0015</option>
                    <option value="0016">0016</option>
                    <option value="0017">0017</option>
                    <option value="0018">0018</option>
                    <option value="0019">0019</option>
                    <option value="0020">0020</option>
                    <option value="0021">0021</option>
                    <option value="0022">0022</option>
                    <option value="0023">0023</option>
                    <option value="0024">0024</option>
                    <option value="0025">0025</option>
                    <option value="0026">0026</option>
                    <option value="0027">0027</option>
                    <option value="0028">0028</option>
                    <option value="0029">0029</option>
                    <option value="0030">0030</option>
                    <option value="0031">0031</option>
                    <option value="0032">0032</option>
                    <option value="0033">0033</option>
                    <option value="0034">0034</option>
                    <option value="0035">0035</option>
                    <option value="0036">0036</option>
                    <option value="0037">0037</option>
                    <option value="0038">0038</option>
                    <option value="0039">0039</option>
                    <option value="0040">0040</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" id="Button0" value="MoveLayout!"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
var customSelectFields = new Array();


// Note: The list of selects to be modified! By Questor
customSelectFields[0] = "Select0";
customSelectFields[1] = "Select1";
customSelectFields[2] = "Select2";
customSelectFields[3] = "Select3";
customSelectFields[4] = "Select4";

$(document).ready(function()
{
    
    
    //Note: To debug! By Questor
    $("#Button0").click(function(event){ AddTestDiv(); });
    
    StartUpCustomSelect(null);  
    
});


//Note: To test! By Questor
function AddTestDiv()
{
    $("#testDiv").append("<div style=\"width:100px;height:100px;\"></div>");
}


//Note: Startup selects customization scheme! By Questor
function StartUpCustomSelect(what)
{
    
    for (i = 0; i < customSelectFields.length; i++)
    {
        
        $("#" + customSelectFields[i] + "").click(function(event){ UpCustomSelect(this); });
        $("#" + customSelectFields[i] + "").wrap("<div id=\"selectDiv_" + customSelectFields[i] + "\" onmouseover=\"BlockCustomSelectAgain();\" status=\"CLOSED\"></div>").parent().after("<div id=\"coverSelectDiv_" + customSelectFields[i] + "\" onclick=\"UpOrDownCustomSelect(this);\" onmouseover=\"BlockCustomSelectAgain();\"></div>");
        
        
        //Note: Avoid breaking the layout when the CSS is modified from "position" to "absolute" on the select! By Questor
        $("#" + customSelectFields[i] + "").parent().css({'width': $("#" + customSelectFields[i] + "")[0].offsetWidth + 'px', 'height': $("#" + customSelectFields[i] + "")[0].offsetHeight + 'px'});
        
        BlockCustomSelect($("#" + customSelectFields[i] + ""));
        
    }
}


//Note: Repositions the div that covers the select using the "onmouseover" event so 
//Note: if element on the screen move the div always stand over it (recalculate! By Questor
function BlockCustomSelectAgain(what)
{
    for (i = 0; i < customSelectFields.length; i++)
    {
        if($("#" + customSelectFields[i] + "").parent().attr("status") == "CLOSED")
        {
            BlockCustomSelect($("#" + customSelectFields[i] + ""));
        }
    }
}


//Note: Does not allow the select to be clicked or clickable! By Questor
function BlockCustomSelect(what)
{
    
    var coverSelectDiv = $(what).parent().next();
    
    
    //Note: Ensures the integrity of the div style! By Questor
    $(coverSelectDiv).removeAttr('style');
    
    
    //Note: To resolve compatibility issues! By Questor
    var backgroundValue = "";
    var filerValue = "";
    if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
    {
        backgroundValue = 'url(fakeimage)';
        filerValue = 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(enabled=true, sizingMethod=\'scale\', src=\'fakeimage\' )';
    }
    
    
    //Note: To debug! By Questor
    //'border': '5px #000 solid',
    
    $(coverSelectDiv).css({
        'position': 'absolute', 
        'top': $(what).offset().top + 'px', 
        'left': $(what).offset().left + 'px', 
        'width': $(what)[0].offsetWidth + 'px', 
        'height': $(what)[0].offsetHeight + 'px', 
        'background': backgroundValue,
        '-moz-background-size':'cover',
        '-webkit-background-size':'cover',
        'background-size':'cover',
        'filer': filerValue
    });
    
}


//Note: Allow the select to be clicked or clickable! By Questor
function ReleaseCustomSelect(what)
{
    
    var coverSelectDiv = $(what).parent().next();
    
    $(coverSelectDiv).removeAttr('style');
    $(coverSelectDiv).css({'display': 'none'});
    
}


//Note: Open the select! By Questor
function DownCustomSelect(what)
{
    
    
    //Note: Avoid breaking the layout. Avoid that select events be overwritten by the others! By Questor
    $(what).css({
        'position': 'absolute', 
        'z-index': '100'
    });
    
    
    //Note: Open dropdown! By Questor
    $(what).attr("size","10");
    
    ReleaseCustomSelect(what);
    
    
    //Note: Avoids the side-effect of the select loses focus.! By Questor
    $(what).focus();
    
    
    //Note: Allows you to select elements using the enter key when the select is on focus! By Questor
    $(what).keyup(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13)
        {
            UpCustomSelect(what);
        }
    });
    
    
    //Note: Closes the select when loses focus! By Questor
    $(what).blur(function(e){
        UpCustomSelect(what);
    });
    
    $(what).parent().attr("status", "OPENED");
    
}


//Note: Close the select! By Questor
function UpCustomSelect(what)
{
    
    $(what).css("position","static");
    
    
    //Note: Close dropdown! By Questor
    $(what).attr("size","1");
    
    BlockCustomSelect(what);
    
    $(what).parent().attr("status", "CLOSED");
    
}


//Note: Closes or opens the select depending on the current status! By Questor
function UpOrDownCustomSelect(what)
{
    
    var customizedSelect = $($(what).prev().children()[0]);
    
    if($(what).prev().attr("status") == "CLOSED")
    {
        DownCustomSelect(customizedSelect);
    }
    else if($(what).prev().attr("status") == "OPENED")
    {
        UpCustomSelect(customizedSelect);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I created a jsfiddle with this, and it does not appear to be working... http://jsfiddle.net/rL53xj11/

Comment: Didn't work for me either.

Comment: @JonCoombs Yes, it works. I have a client application where this solution is running perfectly. Note, however, that this code is already 2 years old. I recommend testing on an html file on your local machine yourself. Also note the version of your jquery.

Comment: @EduardoLucio Can you convert it into a code sample on here?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Come back to the "basic" =D ! Create a folder. Download the "jquery-1.3.2.js" http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.2.js, creating a file ("my.htm") with the contents of "HTML CODE" and a file ("CustomSelect.js") with the contents of "JAVASCRIPT CODE". Put everything inside the folder you created. Double-click in "my.htm" to open it in your browser. Done! Thanks! =D

Answer (score -3):

```
<select id="myDropDown">
  <option>html5</option>
  <option>javascript</option>
  <option>jquery</option>
  <option>css</option>
  <option>sencha</option>
</select>
```

By jQuery:

```
var myDropDown=$("#myDropDown");
var length = $('#myDropDown> option').length;
//open dropdown
myDropDown.attr('size',length);
//close dropdown
myDropDown.attr('size',0);
```

By javascript:

```
var myDropDown=document.getElementById("myDropDown");
var length = myDropDown.options.length;
//open dropdown
myDropDown.size = length;
//close dropdown
myDropDown.size = 0;
```

Copied from:
[Open close select](http://html5wood.com/how-to-automatically-openclose-dropdown-with-javascript-and-jquery/)

Comment: This isn't opening the select, this is expanding it.

Answer (score -12):

```
//use jquery
$select.trigger('mousedown')
```

Comment: Have tested in Firefox 37 and Chrome 41 to confirm this does not work currently.

Comment: Maybe it's time to delete this answer.

Comment: In vanilla js would be `$select.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown', { bubbles: true }))`, so no need for jquery. None the less, the code doesn't open the dropdown list, for security reasons.