# Jquery: Expanding select option on hover

Tags: jquery

How can i expand/open the select option on mouseover using jquery to show all the items in the select list?

```
    <select size="3" id="something">
       <option value="1">.1..</option>
       <option value="2">.2..</option>
 <option value="3">.3..</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: This answer also said "no" -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430237/is-it-possible-to-use-js-to-open-an-html-select-to-show-its-option-list

Comment: @Minime unless you use the Chosen plugin linked in my comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean something like this.

```
$('select').hover(function(){
    var count = $(this).children().length;
    $(this).attr('size', count);
},function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('size');
});
```

This will add and remove the size attribute when the select is hovered over. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bplumb/GE86L/1/).

Comment: on mouseover i want the select to just openup/expand and show all its items/lists

Comment: @user244394 I am sorry but a standard select doesn't support this functionality. The best I can think of is to get the the number of children in the select and expand it to that size.