# Open DropDownList when mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a DropDownList in a updatepanel  and bind it in code behind.

```
 <span id="dropdown" class='css-select-moz groupTitle' style="margin-right: 880px; padding-top: 0; margin-top: 0px; background: transparent">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="SubCategoryDropDownList" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SubCategoryDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" CssClass="css-select"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </span>
```

and style

```
 .css-select {
-moz-appearance: window;
background-position: left bottom;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
padding: 2px;
border: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
text-indent: 0.01px;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
background: transparent;
color: #FF8000;
}
```

I want open DropDown when mouse over, I use this script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#SubCategoryDropDownList").hover(function(){
$(this).trigger('click');
 });
})
```

But don't open items, How to open DropDownList when mouse over?

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/q/14861117/1636522.

Comment: I use this code, But my problem is not solved:(

Comment: Check comments and answers, there are plenty of links about that.

Comment: Sorry, but I've searched the internet and the website and then I raised my question

Answer (score 0):

See you used [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) and you have to specify the click in the code to trigger, since it is not there the trigger won't be executed.

#### Note:

> Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type.

What it means is this:

```
$("#foo").on( "click", function() { //<--the given event type "click"
   alert('clicked');
});
$("#foo").trigger("click"); // <---triggering the same event type "click"
```

#### From the documentation:

> Any event handlers attached with .on() or one of its shortcut methods are triggered when the corresponding event occurs. They can be fired manually, however, with the .trigger() method. A call to .trigger() executes the handlers in the same order they would be if the event were triggered naturally by the user:

Comment: Thanks, Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

What Hiral answered should do the trick BUT have in mind that it is a completely client handled functionality and you should either remove the `AutoPostback="True"` or utilize some sort of AJAX  in order to do this. When the option's click event is triggered a **PostBack** occurs. Now the catch is that the option box in the response is still closed, so you don't notice the effect of the client script.

Comment: This is not enough since the trigger of the partial update is the DropDownList itself. So the UpdatePanel provided functionality won't do the magic you're looking for since the UpdatePanel updates only the TRIGGER's HTML, not the whole page :)

Answer (score 0):

refer This `Fiddel` It will Help you To understand :`http://jsfiddle.net/AndreasPizsa/NzvKC/`
:-)

Comment: Thanks, but i want to use dropdown for select a item.

Comment: There is no information here except for a link to JSFiddle, and even that isn't a live link.