# How to open an HTML select tag by custom button?

Tags: html, select, triggers

I'm developing a web page for mobile phones, and I need to implement a custom design for select tags. I need to place a button near (over) the select tag and it should open, "fire-up" options.

For a better understanding I made a screenshot:

[image]

If the red button is clicked it should open the select tag.

What have I tried:

```
<style type="text/css">
#trigger_button { width:20px;height:20px;background:red;float:left;margin-left:-15px; }
</style>

<body>
    <p>Foo Select</p>

    <table>
    <tr><td>
       <select name='foo_select' style='float:left;' id='foo_select'>
          <option value='1'>test AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 1</option>
          <option value='2'>test BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB 2</option>
          <option value='3'>test CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC 3</option>
        </select>

        <div id='trigger_button' onclick="$('#foo_select').trigger('click');"></div>
    </td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

**Notice!**

On Android OS Chrome browser will react different like on PC! On Android Chrome the options are showing in a different scrollable frame (like a pop-up).

Is this possible? Can I open a select tag with a custom button?

Comment: Answer is YES, you can do it with JavaScript, use google, you'll get 100's of examples

Comment: @Mr.Alien before opening this thread I have searched but believe me I haven't found any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think it's possible but there are always workarounds... check this out

[Is it possible to use JS to open an HTML select to show its option list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430237/is-it-possible-to-use-js-to-open-an-html-select-to-show-its-option-list)

Answer (score 1):

Did you checked this out?

http://www.designdim.com/2011/07/10-important-jquery-selectboxdropdown-plugins/

It is possible to do with JavaScript or jQuery also

Comment: And how am I supposed to use this on mobile? I need to use the default chrome pop-up window that will fire up if I'm touching the select tag.

Comment: @ZbarceaChristian that is a default behavior of androids right?

Comment: Default behavior for Chrome on Android.

Comment: @ZbarceaChristian Ok ok I though you want to customize the dropdown button with the image, I'll delete my answer :)

Comment: Don't delete it, it's useful but not in my case. I need a button to fire-up options.

Comment: @ZbarceaChristian Ya my bad, I didn't understood your question quiet well

Comment: @ZbarceaChristian Am upvoting your question as am curious to know something about this