# OnClick Function which opens my dropdown box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a `select` and a `label`. Now on click of the `label` I want the select box to open. What is the best way to do this?

```
<label>         
    <select id="Place" data-bind="options: Titles, optionsCaption: 'Going?', optionsValue: 'place', value: Location"></select>
</label>
```

Does anyone know how I can, when the `label` is clicked, open the `select`? I would prefer a javascript option as it means it will be called everytime, as I am having a Internet explorer issue.

Comment: when you click a `select` it will open and your `select` is the only thing in the `label`. So is it not doing what you want already? If you want them completely separated, I'm not sure it's possible.

Comment: You can't without actually clicking on the `select`. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430237/is-it-possible-to-use-js-to-open-an-html-select-to-show-its-option-list)

Comment: as @Rhumborl said me too dont think it can be done as opening select box cannot be accessed from js it is browser event

Comment: Here are some ways to do it

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `select` does not have any options in it, therefore it cannot display any data when clicked. If you give your `select` options then you will be able to pick items. Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zndwsb12/