# Open HTML select dropdown programmatically

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, select, mouseevent

I am trying to open programmatically a select box (html dropdown/select box, notfile picker) in javascript using this code

https://jsfiddle.net/Dj7ak/13/

```
function openSelect() {

     var element = document.getElementById("s")
       var worked = false;
     if (document.createEvent) { // all browsers
         var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
         e.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);


         worked = element.dispatchEvent(e);

     } else if (element.fireEvent) { // ie
         worked = element.fireEvent("onmousedown");
     }

 }
```

but only seems to work in chrome. Not in ie 11 not in firefox.

Anyone any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: This is not a firefox addon so i remoed that tag.

Comment: This topic has some hacks to make it work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430237/is-it-possible-to-use-js-to-open-an-html-select-to-show-its-option-list