# How to open select box when pressing tab key?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, select, angularjs-directive

When pressing the <kbd>tab</kbd> key, the focus changes to another field. What I want is that, when the focus comes to a `<select>`, the option list is shown.

This is working:

```
  <div ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
  <input type="text" /><br>
    <input type="text" /><br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state for state in states " />

</div>
```

This is not working:

```
<div ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
  <input type="text" /><br>
    <input type="text" /><br>
    <!-- this is not working -->
    <select  ng-model="selected" >
                            <option value="aa">aa</option>
                            <option value="bb">bb</option>
                        </select>
</div>
```

My plunker code is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/2optNOlEemRvcQb1VrRX?p=preview).

Comment: Possibly related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430237/is-it-possible-to-use-js-to-open-an-html-select-to-show-its-option-list

Comment: @srkprasad did you looked at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take use of this directive which will open select box on focus

**Directive**

```
.directive('openSelect', function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'AE',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      element.on('focus', function(){
        element.prop('size',element[0].options.length);
      })
      element.on('blur change', function(){
        element.prop('size',1);
      })
    }
  }
})
```

**Markup**

```
<select ng-model="selected" open-select>
  <option value="aa">aa</option>
  <option value="bb">bb</option>
</select>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/HiABwudoJjQMRGN65PoD?p=preview)