# programmatically open a bootstrap select

Tags: bootstrap-select

I need to programmatically **open** a [bootstrap select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/), not **show** like [documentation](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/#show) says 

(it affects displaying)

It seems to be a missing method, so how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [toggle](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickertoggle) method. It programmatically toggles the bootstrap-select menu open/closed.

```js
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('toggle');
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried the documentation and it wasn't working for me either, so I did some research and apparently opening a `select` list is not an easy thing to do programatically with JavaScript.

check out this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430237/is-it-possible-to-use-js-to-open-an-html-select-to-show-its-option-list) and this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due).

What I would probably recommend is to use a Bootstrap `.btn-dropdown` instead of a `select` list if possible?