# How to open dropdown list clicking on icon?

Tags: jquery

So what i want to achive is when user click on `i` to open dropdown list and when user click again to close that dropdown list. Any suggestion?

```
<li>
    <select id="dropdown" class="dropdown">
           <option value="EN">EN</option>
           <option value="BS">BS</option>
           <option value="DE">DE</option>

    </select>
    <i id="arrow" class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
</li>
```

Comment: Read up on css and replacing div's in the dom tree, or use something like x-tag or pollyfill. Then propose your solution here if it does not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use JS to open an HTML select to show it's option list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430237/is-it-possible-to-use-js-to-open-an-html-select-to-show-its-option-list)

Comment: that was 6 years ago...really???

Comment: but still the answer is NO... `:)`! Go for select2 plugin for that matter https://select2.github.io/