# Selenium IDE - Open dropdown

Tags: automation, automated-tests, selenium-ide

Is it possible to make selenium IDE open a dropdown menu to show all options? I have a test case where I need to open a dropdown and take a screenshot as evidence of all options there ... but can't figure out a way to do this. P.s: the click option does not do anything, already tried it.

Comment: Could you provide the html fragment with the select and options?

Comment: `<select id="LANGUAGE" class="iform" size="" name="LANGUAGE">
<option value="en_US"> - Select from list - (en_US)</option>
<option value="frCA"> Canada Canadian French</option>
<option selected="" value="enUS"> United States English</option>
</select>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
storeXpathCount | //select[@id='LANGUAGE']/option | count
storeEval       | window.document.getElementById('LANGUAGE').setAttribute('size', ${count}) | lol
```

But I don't know why do you need a screenshot to prove something while you can just check it by standart selenium IDE command:

```
assertText | id=LANGUAGE | - Select from list - (en_US) Canada Canadian French United States English
```

Comment: It modifies the dropdown appearance ... the test is to validate the UI ... I must prove in a screenshot that the dropdown works and show the options, is not actually to validade the options there :-)

Comment: In that case I suppose nobody can help you.

Comment: Selenium IDE is using javascript to perform actions on the page. But that is impossible to open dropdown with javascript. Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430237/is-it-possible-to-use-js-to-open-an-html-select-to-show-its-option-list. That's why that is impossible to do with selenium IDE too.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.clickAndHold(driver.findElement(By.id("dropdownid"))).build().perform();
    //you need to release the control from the test
    //actions.MoveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("dropdownid"))).Release();
```

Comment: Isn't this on Selenium Webdriver? I'm using Selenium IDE, Firefox extension :-)