# how to open dropdown in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

can we open the dropdown when it focus using tab keyword .I want to open the drop down while using tab navigation .

Example if I am in input field (focus to input field ) then if I press tab focus goes to button then drop down , here I want to open the drop down
here is my code
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RGKKrd?editors=1010

```
angular.module('app',[ ]).directive('abc',function(){
  return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function (scope, element ,attr) {
            element.on('keydown', function (evt) {
                if (evt.which ===9) {
                   // evt.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
  }
})
```

Comment: I think it might be helpful.. [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430237/is-it-possible-to-use-js-to-open-an-html-select-to-show-its-option-list)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot programmatically open a `select`

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430237/is-it-possible-to-use-js-to-open-an-html-select-to-show-its-option-list) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due)

If you are looking for a workaround **[here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ampWYk?editors=1010)** is something I have made. 
Navigate to the `select box` with `tab key` and select your `option`. The `select` will stay open as long as it is in `focus`. It closes on `focusout`

Here is the directive

```
angular.module('app',[ ]).directive('abc',function(){
  return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function (scope, element ,attr) {

            element.on('keyup', function (evt) {
                if (evt.which ===9) {
                  var length = element.find("option").length;
                  element.attr("size",length);
                  //element.attr("size",0);
                }
            });

            element.on('keydown', function (evt) {
                if (evt.which ===9) {
                  var length = element.find("option").length;
                  element.attr("size",0);
                  //element.attr("size",0);
                }
            });

        }
  }
})
```

Not the best solution, but close to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You Can not do it, But there is some work around kind of code you can go with.
You can change your Js code like this.

```
  angular.module('app',[ ]).directive('abc',function(){
   return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    link: function (scope, element ,attr) {
        element.on('keydown', function (evt) {
          if (evt.which ===9) {
            //debugger;
            if(document.activeElement.localName==="select"){
                        angular.element(document.activeElement).attr("size",1);
             }
            if(document.activeElement.nextElementSibling!==null && document.activeElement.nextElementSibling.localName==="select"){
            angular.element(document.activeElement.nextElementSibling).attr("size",document.activeElement.nextElementSibling.childElementCount);
            }

            }
        });

    }
  }
 })
```

This is not a proper solution , just a workaround