# Simulate Click on Select Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need to simulate a click event on a select element to show the options. i found this http://jsfiddle.net/joya/rD3nn/ but it don't work in chrome and firefox. In safari it works.

this is my code:

```
$(document).on('keypress', function (e) {
    if(e["keyCode"] == 13){

        //Bei Enter-Eingabe das Dropdown öffnen
        var elem = $('#select');
        if (document.createEvent) {
            var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            e.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            elem[0].dispatchEvent(e);
        } else if (element.fireEvent) {
            elem[0].fireEvent("onmousedown");
        }

    }
});
```

how i can solve this problem for chrome and firefox ?

Comment: Try `elem.click()`.

Comment: I don't believe Chrome lets you do this. Either way, faking events and hacking around the standard behaviour of a control isn't a very good idea. If you need to do this, use a select-style plugin, such as Select2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430237/is-it-possible-to-use-js-to-open-an-html-select-to-show-its-option-list)

Comment: elem.click() dont work

Comment: the linked answer doesent work too