# dynamically open dropdown in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

how do i open up a dynamically created dropdown using native vue and javascript?

```
<select ref="dropdown">
    <option v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
        {{item}}
    </option>
</select>
```

under my methods i have tried these to no avail:

```
openDropdown () {
    let el = this.$refs.dropdown;
    // this doesnt work
    el.click();
    // this doesnt work
    el.setAttribute('visible', true);
    // this also doesnt work
    el.style.show = true;
}
```

any tips or tricks would be helpful, thanks!
This has to use native Vue. i understand JavaScript wont suffice on its own, but there has to be a way that Vue is able to do this. And i cannot use jQuery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use JS to open an HTML select to show its option list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430237/is-it-possible-to-use-js-to-open-an-html-select-to-show-its-option-list)

Comment: this is for vue, so i would appreciate a vue solution if there is one

Comment: Vue is javascript.  If javascript can't do it, Vue cannot either.

Comment: but jQuery can do it, so im hoping there is a way that Vue can do it

Comment: jQuery is also javascript, so I would question where you've seen an example of this.  There are alternatives to make this work by not using a <select> and instead using a plugin that looks like a dropdown that gives javascript more options.  But, again, those are not <select> like in this case.  Examples, http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/ , https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/ , https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage

Comment: i cant use jQuery

Comment: I'm not suggesting to use jQuery.  I'm simply pointing out why it doesn't work with jQuery and why plugins have been made to make up for this deficiency with the native <select> tag.  Which isn't really a deficiency, but more of a security thing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems they keep renaming the property to do this. In Vuetify 2.2.11 it seems to be:

```
this.$refs["mySelect"].isMenuActive = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Call focus() and set isMenuActive = true

Answer (score -1):

1) Set v-select input ID: inputId="vs__search"
2) Set method:

```
openSearch() {
    let toggleBtn = document.getElementById('vs__search');
    let dropDown = document.querySelectorAll('.filters__search.vs__dropdown-menu')[0];
    if (dropDown) {
         toggleBtn.blur();
    } else {
         toggleBtn.focus();
    }
},
```

Answer (score -2):

If using VueSelect 2, the solution I came up with was using `activate()` method:

```
<v-select :options="options" ref="dropdown"></v-select>

mounted: function() {
   const dropdown  = this.$refs.dropdown;
   dropdown.activate()
}
```