# I'm using react redux with eslint enabled. Need to open a <Select> element if a text input has some valid value

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a simple  element, which im trying to display open programatically if the value is valid in a particular text field. 
With ref Im able to get the select object but I dunno how to open it.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: [no good news for you i'm afraid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/430241/3148807)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use JS to open an HTML select to show its option list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430237/is-it-possible-to-use-js-to-open-an-html-select-to-show-its-option-list)