# Have any events select element can dispatch to pop options?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I need click a div to pop the options in the event. My code are as followed.

```
<div class="value" @click.native="onClick">
    <select v-if="mode=='select'" ref="selectNative">
        <option value="volvo">one</option>
        <option value="saab">two</option>
        <option value="mercedes">three</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I use Vue get Dom element by ref and bind onClick on div

```
this.$refs.selectNative.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', { 'bubbles': false }));
```

but it doesn't work.

I want to get options when click the div.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Wha do you mean by *"pop the options"*?

Comment: It means like click <select/> @acdcjunior

Comment: what exactly you wanted to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use JS to open an HTML select to show its option list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430237/is-it-possible-to-use-js-to-open-an-html-select-to-show-its-option-list)

Comment: ok, got it @Jacob Goh

Answer (score 0):

You should  try `MouseEvent` instead of simple '`Event`'

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried it but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add the `@click` to the `<select>` and use `@click="onClick($event.currentTarget)"`?

```
<div class="value" @click="onClick($refs.selectNative)">
    <select v-if="mode=='select'" ref="selectNative" @click="onClick($event.currentTarget)">
        <option value="volvo">one</option>
        <option value="saab">two</option>
        <option value="mercedes">three</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.And I want to the result that when you have clicked the div area just like you have clicked the select element.

Comment: See `@click="onClick($refs.selectNative)"` in the updated answer.