# selected text to display in input box using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have a multiple select dropdown using selectpicker and i want to display the selected text in another input box with @selected name not the value. 
[image] 
In this on click of plus a dropdown should open and after selecting the plus remains but the selected text has to display in another input box.
here is the code that i have tried
HTML code

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 


 <select id='recruiter' name="recruiter"  class="selectpicker" multiple>
     <optgroup label="Camping">
    <option value="1">Tent</option>
    <option value="2">Flashlight</option>
    <option value="3">Toilet Paper</option>
  </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="fruits">
    <option value="6">apple</option>
    <option value="7">orange</option>
    <option value="8">banana</option>
  </optgroup>
  </select>
 <input type="text" class="width-100 chat-borderTB pad-5" placeholder="comment" aria-describedby="sizing-addon2" name="msg" id="msg">


  <script type="text/javascript">
         $("#recruiter").on("change",function(){

           update();
         });

         function update() {

var selected=[];
 $('#recruiter :selected').each(function(){
     selected[$(this).val()]=$(this).text();
    });
 // alert($.trim(selected));
console.log(selected);
         $("#msg").val(selected);
         }
      </script>
```

Can u suggest how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var selected=[];
 $('#recruiter option:selected').each(function(){
     selected[$(this).val()]=$.trim($(this).text());
    });
console.log(selected);
         $("#msg").val(selected);
         }
```

Comment: thank you but i need the @ symbol before the selected item eg: if we select a,b,c then it should display as @a @b @c

Comment: Simple string  concatenation will solve that .  selected[$(this).val()]="@"+$.trim($(this).text());

Comment: can we do like on click of a button dropdown opens

Comment: check this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430237/is-it-possible-to-use-js-to-open-an-html-select-to-show-its-option-list

Comment: can we give the placeholder for the select dropdown using selectpicker

Comment: Use title attribute in select element .  <select id='recruiter' title="placeholder" >

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171454/discussion-between-nihar-sarkar-and-lakshmi-priya).

Comment: in bootstrap selectpicker if we select two or more it will count and it will show as 3 items selected can we remove the word items selected

Comment: didn't get you . if you have farther question , please add another question with codes . that will better to understand the issue . Don't forget to mark solved , if the problem of this question is solved . Thank you .

Comment: i need to count the number of items selected ,so i am using this  <select id='recruiter' name="recruiter"  class="selectpicker" multiple  data-selected-text-format="count"> it shows as the number of items selected with the text 3 items selected .in this i want to remove the text "items selected" i need only the count

Comment: use JS replace() method .  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace