# How can i fire select tag option list using multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, html

How can i display the options from select-option tag with different button

I have a div or maybe another button. From this button i need to view the list of option from my select tag

my select tag is:

```
<select>
      <option value="0" selected="selected">Choose a class...</option>
      <option value="1" >2</option>
      <option value="2" >3</option>
      <option value="3" >4</option>
</select>
```

and then my another button from where if i click this button i should see the list of above option (at above location)

```
   <button>My button</button>
```

Comment: Do you want to list out all the options or open the select menu?

Comment: open select menu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use JS to open an HTML select to show its option list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430237/is-it-possible-to-use-js-to-open-an-html-select-to-show-its-option-list)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that there is no way to open the select like **default select open action**.

But there's another way that may meet your requirement.

Here is an example to open `select options` by changing the `size` attribute.

```js
var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var size = select.getAttribute("size");
  
  if(size == null || size == 0){
    // you can determine the height of opening select
    select.setAttribute("size", 5);
  }
  else{
    select.setAttribute("size", 0);
  }
}, false);

select.addEventListener("change", function(){
    this.setAttribute("size", 0);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
      <option value="0" selected="selected">Choose a class...</option>
      <option value="1" >2</option>
      <option value="2" >3</option>
      <option value="3" >4</option>
</select>

<button>My button</button>
```

Comment: can this be implemented on angular/typescript?

Comment: This is pure JavaScript. I think it should work fine.