# Is it possible to open React-Select component as it mounts?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Not just focusing, but to actually open the component and display options. 
I know this isn't simple on a regular select component (see [Is it possible to use JS to open an HTML select to show its option list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430237/is-it-possible-to-use-js-to-open-an-html-select-to-show-its-option-list) ), but perhaps it is still possible with React-Select.

Comment: Just to summarize, the first your select will mount you want to open it ?

Comment: @Laura, This is correct.

Comment: @Laura's answer is excellent. Unfortunately, this cannot be achieved using a standard Select element. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430237/is-it-possible-to-use-js-to-open-an-html-select-to-show-its-option-list

Answer (score 2):

In `react-select` you can control the opening of the menu with `menuIsOpen` props. to achieve your goal I would use a combination of `menuIsOpen`, `onInputChange` and `onFocus` like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      menuIsOpen: true
    };
  }

  onInputChange = (options, { action }) => {
    if (action === "menu-close") {
      this.setState({ menuIsOpen: false });
    }
  };

  onFocus = e => {
    this.setState({ menuIsOpen: true });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Select
          options={options}
          onFocus={this.onFocus}
          onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
          menuIsOpen={this.state.menuIsOpen}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`onInputChange` can receive the following events:

```
"set-value",
"input-change",
"input-blur",
"menu-close"
```

Depending of what kind of behaviour you're expecting I would update this [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/ww90lnkvq5).

Comment: It doesn't open again if an item is selected and the select `isMulti`. It only opens again if I remove the cursor from within the select and focus again.