# How do you open a dropdown menu/datalist using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to open the dropdown menu using Javascript. The "Ask For More Time" button is supposed to open the dropdown menu by using `focus()` and `select()` javascript code but it's not working for the dropdown menu. What JS code do you use to open the dropdown menu?

**HTML:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>replit</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
<form>
<input list="Ask" name="Ask">
  <datalist id="Ask" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
    <option value="One More Minute">
    <option value="Send Request">
    <option value="Enter Screen Time Passcode">
    <option value="Cancel">
  </datalist>
     <button type="submit" id="submit">Send</button>
  <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="https://classroom.google.com/u/0/h">
</form>
     <button onclick=oncl() class="button button5">Ask For More Time</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function oncl() {
  const datalist = document.getElementById('Ask');
  datalist.focus();
  datalist.select();
}
```

Comment: what is <script src="script.js"></script> in the body ?

Comment: It just connects the javascript in the html

Comment: you want to open same dropdown with button outside the form ?

Comment: I tried to put the button in the form but it still didn't work.

Comment: you can refer this question
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430237/is-it-possible-to-use-js-to-open-an-html-select-to-show-its-option-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430237/is-it-possible-to-use-js-to-open-an-html-select-to-show-its-option-list)