# Select HTML element on hover

Tags: label, alignment, dropdown, width, html-select

I am trying to insert in a form a select tag similar to this:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select

The only thing thing that I would like to make different from the usual select element that I want the options to be displayed on hover instead on click event.

I was trying this at that particular select element

```
.p-type:hover option{
display: block;
}
```

and I also was trying with a dropdown https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp At this one my issue is that when I put a  to it the dropdown list justifies/aligns to the label and not to the dropdown box itself.

Comment: It would help if you used edited your question and used the snippet tool `<>`

Comment: This cannot be done, neither using CSS nor JS. https://stackoverflow.com/q/430237/383904 - I would suggest you use a custom select box, not the OS one.